# Java Spring @Transactional method not rolling back as expected

Tags: java, spring, transactions

Below is a quick outline of what I'm trying to do. I want to push a record to two different tables in the database from one method call. If anything fails, I want everything to roll back. So if `insertIntoB` fails, I want anything that would be committed in `insertIntoA` to be rolled back.

```
public class Service {
    MyDAO dao;

    public void insertRecords(List<Record> records){
        for (Record record : records){
            insertIntoAAndB(record);
        }
    }

    @Transactional (rollbackFor = Exception.class, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void insertIntoAAndB(Record record){
        insertIntoA(record);
        insertIntoB(record);
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void insertIntoA(Record record){
        dao.insertIntoA(record);
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void insertIntoB(Record record){
        dao.insertIntoB(record);
    }

    public void setMyDAO(final MyDAO dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }
}
```

Where `MyDAO dao` is an interface that is mapped to the database using mybatis and is set using Spring injections.

Right now if `insertIntoB` fails, everything from `insertIntoA` still gets pushed to the database. How can I correct this behavior?

EDIT:

I modified the class to give a more accurate description of what I'm trying to achieve. If I run `insertIntoAAndB` directly, the roll back works if there are any issues, but if I call `insertIntoAAndB` from `insertRecords`, the roll back doesn't work if any issues arise.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found the solution!

Apparently Spring can't intercept internal method calls to transactional methods. So I took out the method calling the transactional method, and put it into a separate class, and the rollback works just fine. Below is a rough example of the fix.

```
public class Foo {
    public void insertRecords(List<Record> records){
        Service myService = new Service();
        for (Record record : records){
            myService.insertIntoAAndB(record);
        }
    }
}

public class Service {
    MyDAO dao;

    @Transactional (rollbackFor = Exception.class, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void insertIntoAAndB(Record record){
        insertIntoA(record);
        insertIntoB(record);
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void insertIntoA(Record record){
        dao.insertIntoA(record);
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void insertIntoB(Record record){
        dao.insertIntoB(record);
    }

    public void setMyDAO(final MyDAO dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396284/does-spring-transactional-attribute-work-on-a-private-method#4396530; Spring can intercept method callings from same class (and @Transcational also works on private methods) if you use AspectJ instead of Spring proxy

Answer (score 2):

I think the behavior you encounter is dependent on what ORM / persistence provider and database you're using. I tested your case using hibernate & mysql and all my transactions rolled back alright.

If you do use hibernate enable SQL and transaction logging to see what it's doing:

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.transaction=DEBUG
// for hibernate 4.2.2 
// log4j.logger.org.hibernate.engine.transaction=DEBUG
```

If you're on plain jdbc (using spring JdbcTemplate), you can also debug SQL & transaction on Spring level

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.jdbc.core=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.springframework.transaction=DEBUG
```

Double check your autocommit settings and database specific peciular (eg: most DDL will be comitted right away, you won't be able to roll it back although spring/hibernate did so)

Comment: Please post your spring configuration.

Comment: @gerrytan I edited my question to more accurately portray what I'm doing.

Answer (score 2):

Just because jdk parses aop annotation not only with the method, also parse annotation with the target class.
For example, you have method A with @transactional, and method B which calls method A but without @transactional, When you invoke the method B with reflection, Spring AOP will check the B method with the target class has any annotations.
So if your calling method in this class is not with the @transactional, it will not parse any other method in this method.
At last, show you the source code:
org.springframework.aop.framework.jdkDynamicAopProxy.class

```
public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
    ......
    // Get the interception chain for this method.
    List<Object> chain = this.advised.getInterceptorsAndDynamicInterceptionAdvice(method, targetClass);

    // Check whether we have any advice. If we don't, we can fallback on direct
    // reflective invocation of the target, and avoid creating a MethodInvocation.
    if (chain.isEmpty()) {
    // We can skip creating a MethodInvocation: just invoke the target directly
    // Note that the final invoker must be an InvokerInterceptor so we know it does
    // nothing but a reflective operation on the target, and no hot swapping orfancy proxying.
        retVal = AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(target, method, args);
    }
    else {
    // We need to create a method invocation...
        invocation = new ReflectiveMethodInvocation(proxy, target, method, args, targetClass, chain);
    // Proceed to the joinpoint through the interceptor chain.
    retVal = invocation.proceed();
    }
}
```