# How to handle manually transactions while using jdbcTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbctemplate

I have web-app which have functionality 'interpreter SQL'. User can write some commands and execute it.

For example, user want to execute 3x operations:

```
1.  ALTER TABLE "aaab".WHATEVER RENAME TO "Something";
2.  ALTER TABLE "aaab".RESOURCES RENAME TO "SomethingElse";
3.  ALTER TABLE "aaab".EXAMCATEGORIES MODIFY NAME NUMBER;
```

---

### What i want to achieve:

1. If operation 1, 2, 3 was successful then `commit` all 3x operations
2. If operation 1, 2 was successful but 3 was not, then `rollback` all 3x operations

Generally if **any** operation from list was not successful then i want to `rollback` all operations.

---

**So here is my interpreter:**

```
public ArrayList<String> executeSQL(String[] queryRows) {
    ArrayList<String> listException = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < queryRows.length; ++i) {
        String query = queryRows[i];
        if(query.trim().length() > 5 && query.trim().substring(0, 6).toUpperCase().equals("SELECT")){
            try{
                mapList = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query);
                int rows = mapList.size();
                listException.add("Success! { affected rows --> [" + rows + "] }");
                updateFlag = true;
            }catch (DataAccessException exceptionSelect){
                listException.add(exceptionSelect.getCause().getMessage());
                updateFlag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        else if(whatKindOfStatementIsThat(query,"DDL")){
            try{
                jdbcTemplate.execute(query);
                listException.add("Success!");
                updateFlag = true;
            }catch (DataAccessException exceptionDDL){
                listException.add(exceptionDDL.getCause().getMessage());
                updateFlag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        else if (whatKindOfStatementIsThat(query,"DML")){
            try {
                int rows = jdbcTemplate.update(query);
                listException.add("Success! { zaafektowane wiersze --> [" + rows + "] }");
                updateFlag = true;
            }catch (DataAccessException exceptionDML){
                listException.add(exceptionDML.getCause().getMessage());
                updateFlag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        else{
            try{
                jdbcTemplate.execute(query);
                listException.add("Success!");
                updateFlag = true;
            }catch (Exception exception){
                listException.add(exception.getCause().getMessage());
                updateFlag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return listException;
}
```

It is really simple, firstly i check what kind of statement was inputted.
1. If statement is a `select` then i need list of result `mapList = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query);`
2. If statement is a `DDL` then i don't need anything `jdbcTemplate.execute(query);`
3. If statement is a `DML` then i need number of rows affected `int rows = jdbcTemplate.update(query);`
4. Everything else, just execute native query `jdbcTemplate.execute(query);`

I keep my statements inside ArrayList and they are executed one after another in loop.
So for example if i have that loop:

```
public void executeSQL (String[] queryRows){ 
     for(int i = 0; i < queryRows.length; ++i){
          // statements are executed there one after another.
     }
}
```

---

### How can i achieve something like that?

```
public void executeSQL(String[] queryRows){ 
     ...begin()
     for(int i = 0; i < queryRows.length; ++i){
          // statements are executed there one after another.
     }
     if(myCondition)
          ...commit()
     else
          ...rollback()
}
```

---

Comment: Depending on your database DDL statements might be transactional, often they aren't. I know Postgres does support this, but Oracle doesn't. So YMMV.

Comment: What is the database used ? PostgreSQL ? Mysql ? If MySQL, what is the engine ? (InnoDb, MyIsam)

Comment: oracle..........

Answer (score 1):

Annotate your method with [@Transactional](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html), and it will commit only if all operations succeeded if you call it from outside your class

> Describes a transaction attribute on an individual method or on a class

Read more in [Understanding the Spring Framework’s declarative transaction implementation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-decl-explained)

> It is not sufficient to tell you simply to annotate your classes with the `@Transactional` annotation, add `@EnableTransactionManagement` to your configuration, and then expect you to understand how it all works

Comment: Well, i tried @Transactional `(org.springframework.transaction.annotation)` but it doesn't work. My method always commit everything no matter i add @Transactional or not :(

Comment: @Brarord you need to define auto commit false, or check answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17224887/java-spring-transactional-method-not-rolling-back-as-expected

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like that.

```
@Component
class X {
    @Transactional
    public void executeSQL(String[] queryRows){ 
         ...begin()
         for(int i = 0; i < queryRows.length; ++i){
              // statements are executed there one after another.
         }
         if(myCondition)
              ...commit()
         else
              throw new RuntimeException(); //or any other exception
              //or TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly(); (not recomended).

    }

    public void test(){
       executeSQ(...);// won't work
    }
}

@Component
class Y {
    @Autowired
    X x;

    public void test(){
       x.executeSQ(...);//should work
    }
}
```

It will work only if method is invoked from other bean.

Comment: It has no effect :( my queries was commited :(

Comment: https://imgur.com/zMN6uIY result of that method, after change rollbackOnly to true, nothing happens, everything is commited already.

Comment: Do you call transactional method from other bean? or  from the came class?

Comment: Sorry but i don't know what exactly you asking? (Nie rozumiem pytania :<)