# Spring @Transactional rollbackFor not working

Tags: spring, transactions, commit, rollback, transactional

I have a code like below

```
   public abstract class AffltTransactionService implements IAffltTransactionService {
    ....

        @Override
        @Transactional
        public void processTransactions(List<? extends AffltTransaction> transactions) {
            for (AffltTransaction transaction : transactions) {
                if (transaction != null) {
                    processTransaction(transaction);
                }
            }
        }

        private void processTransaction(AffltTransaction transaction) {
            try {
                processTransactionInternal(transaction);

            } catch (Exception exception) {
                affltTransactionError = new AffltTransactionError(null, null, "error", new Date());
                saveAffltTransactionError(affltTransactionError);
                log.error(exception.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }

        @Transactional(readOnly=false, rollbackFor = Exception.class, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
        public void processTransactionInternal(AffltTransaction transaction) {
```

processTransactionInternal throws ServiceUnAvailableException which extends RuntimeException

But the transaction is not getting rolled back despite having rollbackFor = Exception.class .
Can you please help.

Comment: see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4396530/280244 - it explain when the annotation is taken in account. In your case it is not taken in account, therefore there is no roleback.

Answer (score 11):

`@Transactional` annotation won't have any effect if you are calling the method directly, since Spring creates proxies above annotated classes and the aspect-defined functionality is implemented by proxy. So, when you call the method from within your class it doesn't get through proxy, and hence no transcation is created and/or rolled back.

Take a look at the [Spring reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-decl-explained) for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Since you invoke one method from another within the same bean, the Spring AOP doesn't use any advices in this case.

Only `processTransactions` is wrapped with `TransactionInteceptor`.

To make it worked you should configure:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy expose-proxy="true"/>
```

But it isn't recommened, though.

More info here: http://www.intertech.com/Blog/secrets-of-the-spring-aop-proxy

Answer (score 1):

Use getCurrentSession instead of opensession

Answer (score 1):

I know it was asked a long time ago but I faced with the same issue and for me was missing Spring configurantion annotation:

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
```

After write it on ApplicationConfiguration class it was solved. I hope it helps someone on future.

Answer (score 0):

The method you use apply @Transactional should throws exception. Don't use try-catch instead.(I guess you use try-catch in somewhere in your processTransaction function).
Code should be like this:

```
@Transactional
    public void processTransactions(List<? extends AffltTransaction> transactions) threws Exception{
        for (AffltTransaction transaction : transactions) {
            if (transaction != null) {
                processTransaction(transaction);
            }
        }
    }
```