# @Transactional annotation is not working springboot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, spring-transactions

I'm using springboot 2.3.0 with mongodb. `@Transactional` annotation is not working for me. It is not able to rollback the transaction in case of any exception.
ps:Using mongoTemplate it is working.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

My controller class:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/employee/{employeeId}")
public String createEmployee(@PathVariable(value = "employeeId") String employeeId, @RequestBody EmployeePayload payload) {
    
    employeeService.createEmployee(employeeId, payload);
    return "employee successfully added";
}
```

My serviceImpl class

> ```
> @Override
> @Transactional(rollbackFor = {ArithmeticException.class})
> public void createEmployee(String employeeId, EmployeePayload payload) {
>     Employee employee = new Employee("1", "Robert", "24");
>     Document mongoDocument = new Document();
>     mongoTemplate.getConverter().write(employee, mongoDocument);
>     MongoDatabaseFactory mongoDatabaseFactory = new 
>     SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory(properties.getUri()
>             + properties.getDataBase() 
>             + properties.getDbFilter());
>
>     MongoDatabaseUtils.getDatabase(properties.getDataBase(), 
>     mongoDatabaseFactory).getCollection("employee").insertOne(mongoDocument);
>     System.out.println(7 / 0); //To throw an exception
> }
> ```

My MongoConfig class

```
@Configuration public class MongoDBConfig {

    @Bean
    MongoTransactionManager transactionManager(MongoDatabaseFactory dbFactory) {
        return new MongoTransactionManager(dbFactory);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring @Transactional rollbackFor not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22957569/spring-transactional-rollbackfor-not-working)

Comment: What kind of MongoDB deployment is it?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing **@EnableTransactionManagement** annotation.

Comment: I have already added @EnableTransactionManagement in SpringBootApplication class

Comment: When you execute your code, your inserted employee is not deleted?

Comment: No! That is still there

Comment: Did you inject employeeService with Autowired or with constructor injection?

Comment: Autowired the service

Comment: Can you try with some RuntimeException?