# java transaction shouldnot rollback all records

Tags: java, sql, database, spring, transactions

In my application, I am doing the following

```
1. Getting 25 records from the DB.
2. Update every 10 records
   Here I have a loop to update every 10 records.so there will be 3 loops.
   For each loop I need to have a new transaction.(so that only  the 10 record will rollback and not all the records will rollback)   
//line 1  
    getRecords();//25 records from DB  //line 2  
    For(Records r: loop) {  //line 3  
    add 10 records;  //line 4  
    call update method(object with 10 records)   //line 5  
}
  //line 6  
updateRecords()//this method updates the 10 records\\line 7
```

Here I think I need to use @Transaction(REQUIRED) at line 6.
so that only the 10 records will rollback and not all the records will rollback.

Can anyone please confirm if this is the correct approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure the `@Transactional` annotation is set on public method. See

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/49494-transactional-on-private-methods

and

[Does Spring @Transactional attribute work on a private method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396284/does-spring-transactional-attribute-work-on-a-private-method)

If the updateRecords() is private method the annotation won't work.