# Hibernate object created before @Transactional method can't be used after (gets LazyInitializationException)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, lazy-loading

I've looked at a lot of other questions about `LazyInitializationException` and `@Transactional`, and haven't seen anything that seems to help our case.

I apologise for being less than methodical investigating it.  It's not my code but it's fallen into my hands for the time being...

We have code that looks like this:

```
@Entity
class TaskSchedule {
    // fields that make up a task schedule
    Date nextRunTime;
}
```

---

```
@Entity
class Task {
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    List<TaskSchedule> schedules;

    @Transactional
    public void doTask() {
        // run the task

        for (TaskSchedule schedule : schedules) {  /* CRASH HAPPENS HERE */
            // set the schedule's next run time
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
@Component
public class TaskDao {
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Task> getScheduledTasks() {

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Task.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.le("runTime", calendar.getTime()));
        criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

        List<Task> results = criteria.list();
        return results;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class MonitorJob {
    TaskDao taskDao;

    public void runScheduledTasks() {
        // start a read only transaction
        List<Task> tasks = taskDao.getScheduledTasks(); // query database
        // finish the transaction

        for (Task task : tasks) {
            // start a transaction
            task.doTask(); // populate lazy list
            // finish transaction
        }
    }
}
```

We get a `LazyInitializationException` exception when the lazy list `schedules` is iterated over:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: Task.schedules, no session or session was closed
        at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:380)
        at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:372)
        at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:365)
        at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:108)
        at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:272)
        at Task.doTask(Task.java:366)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:197)
        at Task_$$_javassist_43.doTask(Task_$$_javassist_43.java)
        at MonitorJob.runScheduledTasks(MonitorJob.java:106)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor68.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:273)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean$MethodInvokingJob.executeInternal(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.java:299)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:111)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:203)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:520)
```

As far as I can tell, after the `@Transactional` method `doTask` is called for the first item in `tasks`, a whole lot of objects, including all the other lazy `schedules` lists for the remaining items in `tasks`, are removed from the session by having `unsetSession` called on them.  This means that subsequent iterations over `tasks` crash because their lazy lists no longer have an associated session.

I haven't actually been working on this bit of code, but it has started failing recently (after our DB was reloaded).  I can't see why it would have worked in the first place, if the objects get removed from the session.

Comment: Why not `runScheduledTasks()` with `@Transactional` annotated? And I haven't seen before `@Transactional` in entity level method.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, now you got self invocation. Please read all answers at the link I have posted earlier (note that it's also depends on whether you are using AOP proxies or not - but I'm assuming you are). In your current code snippet you need to annotate runScheduledTasks() with the @Transactional and remove @Transactional from getScheduledTasks() cause it's redundant and you don't need transaction for reading database. Also as A Nyar Thar mentioned you don't need to annotate your entity method with @Transactional.

Also from my experience @Transactional annotations are commonly used in service layer. If you wish to update each Task in new transaction when you need to create service method that always opens new transaction.

```
public class TaskService {

    @Transactional(propagation = REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void updateTask(Task task) {
        task.doTask();      
    }

}
```

then in MonitorJob

```
//in this case you don't need @Transactional here
public void runScheduledTasks() {
        ....
        List<Task> tasks = getScheduledTasks();
        for (Task task : tasks) {
            taskService.updateTask(task);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Gosh darn it!  Again, `getScheduledTasks` is only in the same class because I edited the code to make clearer for StackOverflow.  Now that I know how private and self-invocation affects `@Transactional`, I'll know not to do that in future.

Answer (score 0):

@Transactional annotation only works with public methods. Either add @Transactional to runScheduledTasks() method and remove one from getScheduledTasks(), or make getScheduledTasks() public.

Read this for explanation:
[Does Spring @Transactional attribute work on a private method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396284/does-spring-transactional-attribute-work-on-a-private-method)

Comment: Changing the method visibility was in error I introduced when editing the code for SO.  The original uses a `public` method.  Thanks for spotting it!  Any other suggestions?