# Roll back A if B goes wrong. spring boot, jdbctemplate

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, jdbctemplate, spring-transactions

I have a method, 'databaseChanges', which call 2 operations: A, B in iterative way. 'A' first, 'B' last.
'A' & 'B' can be **C**reate, **U**pdate **D**elete functionalities in my  persistent storage, Oracle Database 11g.

Let's say,

'A' update a record in table Users, attribute zip, where id = 1.

'B' insert a record in table hobbies.

**Scenario:** databaseChanges method is been called, 'A' operates and update the record. 'B' operates and try to insert a record, something happen, an exception is been thrown, the exception is bubbling to the databaseChanges method.

**Expected:** 'A' and 'B' didn't change nothing. the update which 'A' did, will be rollback. 'B' didn't changed nothing, well... there was an exception.

**Actual:** 'A' update seems to not been rolled back. 'B' didn't changed nothing, well... there was an exception.

---

**Some Code**

If i had the connection, i would do something like:

```
private void databaseChanges(Connection conn) {
   try {
          conn.setAutoCommit(false);
          A(); //update.
          B(); //insert
          conn.commit();
   } catch (Exception e) { 
        try {
              conn.rollback();
        } catch (Exception ei) {
                    //logs...
        }
   } finally {
          conn.setAutoCommit(true);
   }
}
```

**The problem:** I don't have the connection (see the Tags that post with the question)

I tried to:

```
@Service
public class SomeService implements ISomeService {
    @Autowired
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    @Autowired
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate npjt;

    @Transactional
    private void databaseChanges() throws Exception {   
        A(); //update.
        B(); //insert
    }
}
```

---

My AppConfig class:

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {    
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate() {
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }   
}
```

---

'A' makes the update. from 'B' an exception is been thrown. The update which been made by 'A' is not been rolled back.

From what i read, i understand that i'm not using the @Transactional correctly.
I read and tried several blogs posts and stackverflow Q & A without succeess to solve my problem.

Any suggestions?

---

**EDIT**

There is a method that call databaseChanges() method

```
public void changes() throws Exception {
    someLogicBefore();
    databaseChanges();
    someLogicAfter();
}
```

Which method should be annotated with @Transactional,

changes()? databaseChanges()?

Comment: my parent table sometime doesn't update:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73091178/data-inconsistancy-parent-table-is-not-updated-while-child-table-is-updated

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`@Transactional` annotation in spring works by wrapping your object in a proxy which in turn wraps methods annotated with `@Transactional` in a transaction. Because of that annotation will not work on private methods (as in your example) because *private methods can't be inherited* => they can't be wrapped (this is not true if you use declarative transactions with [aspectj](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-aspectj), then proxy-related caveats below don't apply).

Here is basic explanation of how `@Transactional` spring magic works.

You wrote:

```
class A {
    @Transactional
    public void method() {
    }
}
```

But this is what you actually get when you inject a bean:

```
class ProxiedA extends A {
   private final A a;

   public ProxiedA(A a) {
       this.a = a;
   }

   @Override
   public void method() {
       try {
           // open transaction ...
           a.method();
           // commit transaction
       } catch (RuntimeException e) {
           // rollback transaction
       } catch (Exception e) {
           // commit transaction
       }
   }
}
```

This has limitations. They don't work with `@PostConstruct` methods because they are called before object is proxied. And even if you configured all correctly, transactions are only rolled back on *unchecked* exceptions by default. Use `@Transactional(rollbackFor={CustomCheckedException.class})` if you need rollback on some checked exception.

Another frequently encountered caveat I know:

`@Transactional` method will only work if you call it "from outside", in following example `b()` will not be wrapped in transaction:

```
class X {
   public void a() {
      b();
   }

   @Transactional
   public void b() {
   }
}
```

It is also because `@Transactional` works by proxying your object. In example above `a()` will call `X.b()` not a enhanced "spring proxy" method `b()` so there will be no transaction. As a workaround you have to call `b()` from another bean.

When you encountered any of these caveats and can't use a suggested workaround (make method non-private or call `b()` from another bean) you can use `TransactionTemplate` instead of declarative transactions:

```
public class A {
    @Autowired
    TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;

    public void method() {
        transactionTemplate.execute(status -> {
            A();
            B();
            return null;
        });
    }

...
}
```

**Update**

Answering to OP updated question using info above.

> Which method should be annotated with @Transactional:
>   changes()? databaseChanges()?

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor={Exception.class})
public void changes() throws Exception {
    someLogicBefore();
    databaseChanges();
    someLogicAfter();
}
```

Make sure `changes()` is called "from outside" of a bean, not from class itself and after context was instantiated (e.g. this is not  `afterPropertiesSet()` or `@PostConstruct` annotated method). Understand that spring rollbacks transaction only for unchecked exceptions by default (try to be more specific in rollbackFor checked exceptions list).

Comment: my parent table sometime doesn't update:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73091178/data-inconsistancy-parent-table-is-not-updated-while-child-table-is-updated

Answer (score 21):

> Any `RuntimeException` triggers rollback, and any checked Exception does not.

This is common behavior across all Spring transaction APIs. **By default**, if a `RuntimeException` is thrown from within the transactional code, the transaction will be rolled back.  If a checked exception (i.e. not a `RuntimeException`) is thrown, then the transaction will not be rolled back.

It depends on which exception you are getting inside `databaseChanges` function.
So in order to catch all exceptions all you need to do is to add `rollbackFor = Exception.class`

The change supposed to be on the service class, the code will be like that:

```
@Service
public class SomeService implements ISomeService {
    @Autowired
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    @Autowired
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate npjt;

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    private void databaseChanges() throws Exception {   
        A(); //update
        B(); //insert
    }
}
```

In addition you can do something nice with it so not all the time you will have to write `rollbackFor = Exception.class`. You can achieve that by writing your own custom annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
@Documented
public @interface CustomTransactional {  
}
```

The final code will be like that:

```
@Service
public class SomeService implements ISomeService {
    @Autowired
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    @Autowired
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate npjt;

    @CustomTransactional
    private void databaseChanges() throws Exception {   
        A(); //update
        B(); //insert
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this method works if we have @Transaction annotations used in the methods which are called from parent methods?

Comment: How about using public method?

Comment: I tried this but rollback seems not run, anyone knows the reason?

     @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
        private void databaseChanges() throws Exception {   
            throw new Exception("test");
            A(); //update
            B(); //insert
        }

Comment: my parent table sometime doesn't update:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73091178/data-inconsistancy-parent-table-is-not-updated-while-child-table-is-updated

Answer (score 1):

The first code you present is for UserTransactions, i.e. the application has to do the transaction management. Usually you want the container to take care of that and use the @Transactional annotation. I think the problem in you case might be, that you have the annotation on a private method. I'd move the annotation to the class level

```
@Transactional
public class MyFacade {

public void databaseChanges() throws Exception {   
    A(); //update.
    B(); //insert
}
```

Then it should rollback properly. You can find more details here
[Does Spring @Transactional attribute work on a private method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396284/does-spring-transactional-attribute-work-on-a-private-method)

Comment: You are injecting the class (in my example MyFacade), right? Otherwise the attribute will not be honored. Maybe you can create a very simple example and post all classes. Then it's easier to see what else is going wrong.

Comment: you should move the @Transaction annotation in your sample code to the class. It's will definitely not work when it's on a private method. Can you also show how A() updates the DB? B() can be replaced by if (true) { throw new Exception() }

Comment: I moved @Transaction to the class level. make the method public. still not working.  A() it's a private method that just make jdbcTemplate.update(UPDATE_BLA_BLA, namedParameters);

Comment: I am talking about the code sample in your question. method is still private there, Annotation on the method

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class MyFacade {

@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttribute.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void databaseChanges() throws Exception {   
    A(); //update.
    B(); //insert
}
```

Comment: any explanation why this should be the correct answer would be great!

Comment: I tried, getting: compile error: TransactionManagement cannot be resolved to a type. My class is annotated with @Service.

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be missing is a `TransactionManager`. The purpose of the `TransactionManager` is to be able to manage database transactions. There are 2 types of transactions, programmatic and declarative. What you are describing is a need for a declarative transaction via annotations.

So what you need to be in place for your project is the following:

**Spring Transactions Dependency (Using Gradle as example)**

```
compile("org.springframework:spring-tx")
```

**Define a Transaction Manager in Spring Boot Configuration**

Something like this

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource dataSource)
{
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
}
```

You would also need to add the `@EnableTransactionManagement` annotation (not sure if this is for free in newer versions of spring boot.

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppConfig {
...
}
```

**Add @Transactional**

Here you would add the `@Transactional` annotation for the method that you want to participate in the transaction

```
@Transactional
public void book(String... persons) {
    for (String person : persons) {
        log.info("Booking " + person + " in a seat...");
        jdbcTemplate.update("insert into BOOKINGS(FIRST_NAME) values (?)", person);
    }
};
```

Note that this method **should be public** and not private. You may want to consider putting `@Transactional` on the public method calling `databaseChanges()`.

There are also advanced topics about where `@Transactional` should go and how it behaves, so better to get something working first and then explore this area a bit later:)

After all these are in place (dependency + transactionManager configuration + annotation), then transactions should work accordingly.

**References**

[Spring Reference Documentation on Transactions](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html)

[Spring Guide for Transactions using Spring Boot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/managing-transactions/) - This has sample code that you can play with