# how can I check `@Transactional(rollbackFor={Exception.class})` works

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39096860/roll-back-a-if-b-goes-wrong-spring-boot-jdbctemplate/39180354) about how to wrap JDBCTemplate in Db-transcation

My question is - how can I check this works?

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor={Exception.class})
public int insertLogAndGetId(ConfigActivityLog dbConfigChange) throws Exception {
    int idInDB = -1;
    if(insertLog(dbConfigChange))
    {
        idInDB = getLatestActivityWithStatus(dbConfigChange.actionStatus).id;
    }
    return idInDB;
}
```

I don't use other annotations like:

```
@Service
public class SomeService implements ISomeService {
    @Autowired
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    @Autowired
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate npjt;
```

Comment: If you don't use Spring annotations, I am assuming your service beans would declared either `XML` or `JavaConfig`. But why not use `JUnit`?

Comment: There's no change so there's no reason to rollback?

Comment: if you don't use @service it won't be found by spring, so it is not working. Please clarify your question: what should work, and what exactly you want to know works: is it transactions are rolled back or transaction process? either way you have to do smth to DB inside method.