# Transaction is not getting rollback when use JDBC Declarative Transactions

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate, spring-transactions

I'm trying to do funds tranfer from **Source** Account to **destination** Account using JDBC declarative transaction and JDBC Template.

**Use Case:** If I try to call **fundsTransfer** method when source account does't have enough balance. In that case amount is getting added in destination account even though withdraw() throwing expected InSufficientFundsExceptions.

```
@Autowired
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemp;
-----
-----
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
public void deposit(int accountNumber, double amount) {
    String sql = "select Balance from <TableName> where Account_Number=?";
    double balance = jdbcTemp.queryForObject(sql, Double.class, accountNumber);
    balance = balance + amount;
    String sql2 = "update <TableName> set Balance=? where Account_Number=?";
    jdbcTemp.update(sql2, balance, accountNumber);
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
public void withdraw(int accountNumber, double amount) throws InSufficientFundsExceptions {

    String sql = "select Balance from <TableName> where Account_Number=?";
    double balance = jdbcTemp.queryForObject(sql, Double.class, accountNumber);
    if (balance >= 5000) {
        balance = balance - amount;
        String sql2 = "update <TableName> set Balance=? where Account_Number=?";
        jdbcTemp.update(sql2, balance, accountNumber);
    } else {
        throw new InSufficientFundsExceptions("InSufficientFunds Exception");
    }
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
public void fundsTransfer(int sourceAccountNumber, int destinationAccountNumber, double amount)
        throws InSufficientFundsExceptions {

    deposit(destinationAccountNumber, amount);
    withdraw(sourceAccountNumber, amount);
}
```

**Note:** If we call withdraw() before deposit() in fundsTranser, getting the expected exception.

**Used Data Base** - SQLServer

Could someone help me out here, what I'm missing here? Ideally, the reflected amount in destination account should get rollback because withdraw ends with an exception.

Comment: It appears `InSufficientFundsExceptions` is not a subclass of `RuntimeException`. If that is the case , use [`rollbackFor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html#rollbackFor--) to define the rollback behaviour for method `fundsTransfer()`

Comment: You may want to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39180354/13279831) to similar question

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because Spring by default only rolls back unchecked exceptions. Since your class is a checked exception because it does not extend runtimeException but regular Exception it doesn’t do a rollback.

You can Modify this behavior with the rollBackFor property in the @Transactional annotation and specifying insuffientFundsException.