# Create two separate transactions in JPA within one method call

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-transactions

I've got the following case:

1. Start transaction
2. Fetch object A
3. Update A
4. Commit transaction
5. Perform a long task with A
6. Update A (not necessary within transaction, but it would be nice)

How to accomplish that? I do not want to have locked table during step 5. Steps 1-4 are expected to behave like "SELECT FOR UPDATE". Below is my current code. The method I'm executing is *execute()*. I'm testing it by executing it from different application instances and I'm checking, if instance A is able to do operations on table while instance B is executing *executeJob(job)*.

```
@Service
@Slf4j
@Transactional
public class JobExecutionService {

    private final Environment environment;
    private final TestJobRepository testJobRepository;
    private final TestJobResultRepository testJobResultRepository;

    @Autowired
    public JobExecutionService(Environment environment, TestJobRepository testJobRepository, TestJobResultRepository testJobResultRepository) {
        this.environment = environment;
        this.testJobRepository = testJobRepository;
        this.testJobResultRepository = testJobResultRepository;
    }

    public void execute() {
        TestJob job = getJob();
        executeJob(job);
        finishJob(job);
    }

    @Transactional
    public TestJob getJob() {
        TestJob testJob = testJobRepository.findFirstByStatusOrderByIdAsc(
                0
        );
        testJob.setStatus(1);
        testJobRepository.save(testJob);
        return testJob;
    }

    public void executeJob(TestJob testJob) {
        log.debug("Execution-0: {}", testJob.toString());
        Random random = new Random();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(3000) + 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            log.error("Error", e);
        }
        log.debug("Execution-1: {}", testJob.toString());
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void finishJob(TestJob testJob) {
        testJobResultRepository.save(
                new TestJobResult(
                        null,
                        testJob.getId(),
                        environment.getProperty("local.server.port")
                )
        );
    }

}

public interface TestJobRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<TestJob, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<TestJob> {

    @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    TestJob findFirstByStatusOrderByIdAsc(Integer status);

}
```

Comment: After your edit, now `executeJob(job);` and `finishJob(job);` are different transactions, so what's your questions now?

Comment: Why do you annotate the class and the individual methods with "@Transactional". Adding "@Transactional" to the class means that it applies to each method.

Comment: At class level you need to have `@EnableTransactionManagement` annotation.

Comment: I'v added some info to this post.

@UeliHofstetter Without `@Transaction` on the class I have "javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress".
@hagrawal I have `@EnableTransactionManagement` in my main class, so I think I do not need it in separate classes.
@hagrawal I think it should behave this way I want but while I'm testing it, it seems not.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to annotate private methods with @Transactional. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396284/does-spring-transactional-attribute-work-on-a-private-method  (at least, in proxy mode). The only one public method you have here is `execute()`, so you could either annotate it or the class as a whole.

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy Ok, so I changed these methods to be public.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@Transactional` on private methods does not work in proxy mode: [Does Spring @Transactional attribute work on a private method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396284/does-spring-transactional-attribute-work-on-a-private-method) The only one public method you have here is `execute()`, so you could either annotate it or the class as a whole.

(By the way, if you make `getJob()` and `finishJob()` public, `@Transactional` will still not work for them as they are called from `execute()` method via `this` and not via proxy generated by transaction management infrastructure).

You could drop `@Transactional` from your `JobExecutionService`, move `getJob()` and `finishJob()` (or whatever methods should run in independent transactions) as public methods to a new service like `TransactionalJobExecutionService` and annotate that new service as `@Transactional`.