# Spring ignores @Transactional annotation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

on one of our projects we encountered a problem with Spring ignoring `@Transactional` annotation and then failing with the following error.

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report
>   re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2018-09-13 15:05:18,406
>   ERROR [main] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication Application
>   run failed org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException:
>   No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread
>   - cannot reliably process 'remove' call; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with
>   actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably
>   process 'remove' call at
>   com.my.service.CacheAService.deleteShortTermCache(CacheAService.java:70)
>   ~[classes/:na]

I found similar questions but none of the solutions applied to this case.

- `@EnableTransactionManagement` is present
- Transactional class implements an interface
- Transactional method is public
- Transactional method is not called internally

When I annotate `CacheService` with `@Transactional`, everything works again. But I am trying to understand why would Spring ignore `@Transactional` on `CacheAService`.

I tried logging Spring's transaction interceptor but there is no mention of `CacheA`. This is the only related thing that gets logged.

> 2018-09-13 15:05:18,242 TRACE [main]
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor
>   Don't need to create transaction for
>   [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.deleteByValidity]:
>   This method isn't transactional.

Here is the simplified code. Code is invoked during application startup by Spring's `ContextRefreshedEvent`.

```
@Service
public class CacheService implements Cache {

    @Autowired
    private CacheA cacheAService;
    @Autowired
    private CacheB cacheBService;

    @Override
    public void clearCache() {
        cacheAService.deleteShortTermCache();
        cacheBService.deleteAll();
    }
}

public interface CacheA {
    void deleteShortTermCache();
}

@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class CacheAService implements CacheA {

    @Autowired
    private CacheARepository cacheARepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void deleteShortTermCache() {
        cacheARepository.deleteByValidity(CacheValidity.SHORT_TERM);
    }
}

public interface CacheB {
    void deleteAll();
}

@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class CacheBService implements CacheB {

    @Autowired
    private CacheBRepository cacheBRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void deleteAll {
        cacheBRepository.deleteAll();
    }
}

public enum CacheValidity {
    SHORT_TERM,
    LONG_TERM
}

@Repository
public interface CacheARepository extends JpaRepository<CacheItem, Integer> {
    void deleteByValidity(CacheValidity validity);
}

public enum CacheItemKey {
    AVAILABLE,
    FUTURE,
    AVAILABLE_UTM,
    FUTURE_UTM,
    REGION
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "cache_item")
public class CacheItem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "cache_item_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "cache_item_id_seq", sequenceName = "cache_item_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private CacheItemKey key;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String value;

    @Column(name = "date_modified", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateModified;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private CacheValidity validity;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(final Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public CacheItemKey getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(final CacheItemKey key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(final String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Date getDateModified() {
        return dateModified;
    }

    public void setDateModified(final Date dateModified) {
        this.dateModified = dateModified;
    }

    public CacheValidity getValidity() {
        return validity;
    }

    public void setValidity(final CacheValidity validity) {
        this.validity = validity;
    }

}
```

**Edit:**
After some digging I found this in the logs.

> 2018-09-14 06:24:11,174 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker
>   Bean 'cacheAService' of type [com.my.service.CacheAService] is not
>   eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example:
>   not eligible for auto-proxying)

Comment: Code of `CacheA`, `CacheB`?

Comment: I added the interfaces.

Comment: 1. `deleteByValidity` should be annotated with `@Transactional`, as it triggers a modifying operation. 2. Try `@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true)`, since class methods annotated with `@Transactional` implement interface methods, which themselves have not been annotated with `@Transactional`. Alternatively, move `@Transactional` to the method declarations in interfaces `CacheA` and `CacheB`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We discovered that this issue was **caused by Spring Boot's auto-configuration**. Since auto-configuration already setups the Transaction management, our custom configuration of `@EnableTransactionManagement` broke the instantiation of transaction advisors. Removing of `@EnableTransactionManagement` from our configuration solves the issue.

Comment: { 5h later... } confirm solution in my case (more complex setup with kotlin / spring boot - but already debugged that to few methods were being scanned via spring aop utils)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use only one `Transactional` annotation (in class or method). May be, the problem is with `@Transactional(readOnly = true)`, because you transaction isn't readOnly, I can't sure what `Transactional` annotation is preferred by Spring. Try to use:

```
@Service
public class CacheAService implements CacheA {

    @Autowired
    private CacheARepository cacheARepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void deleteShortTermCache() {
        cacheARepository.deleteByValidity(CacheValidity.SHORT_TERM);
    }
}
```

or

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class CacheAService implements CacheA {

    @Autowired
    private CacheARepository cacheARepository;

    @Override
    public void deleteShortTermCache() {
        cacheARepository.deleteByValidity(CacheValidity.SHORT_TERM);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this does not work. I tried both variants. Strange thing is that only CacheA does not work. When I comment it out cache B works as expected.

Comment: Can you add code CacheARepository, CacheBRepository and code Entities  that is uses in this Repository. Do you have "fetchtype.lazy" or cascade deleted like "@OneToMany (cascade = CascadeType.ALL, ...)" in entities in CacheARepository?

Comment: I added the code. No there are just values. No other entities.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in a familiar situation. For those, who have same problems but the answers won't work.
The `@Transactional`-annotation works per default only on `public`-methods. Not on `private` and not on `package-private`.

See this question for more information and workarounds -> [Does Spring @Transactional attribute work on a private method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396284/does-spring-transactional-attribute-work-on-a-private-method)