# TransactionRequiredException when deleting in threads

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8, jpql

I'm having a problem when I trying to delete data from the DB using multiple threads with Hibernate.

Repo:

```
@Modifying
@Query("DELETE FROM Customer cus  WHERE cus.customerId in :customerIds")
public void deleteByCustomerIds(@Param("customerIds") List<Long> customerIds);
```

Service:

```
public runDelete (List<Long> customerIds) {
    List<List<Long>> partitions = Lists.partition(customerIds, 5000);

    for(int i = 0; i < partitions.size(); i++ ) {
        final int index = i;
        Runnable thread = () -> deleteCustomersInBatches(partitions.get(index));
        new Thread(thread).start();
    }
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
private void deleteCustomerInBatches(List<Long> customerIds) {

    for (List<Long> batch : Lists.partition(oldCalcIds, 1000)) {
        customerRepo.deleteByCustomerIds(batch);
    }
}
```

This is how code looks like, I have the @Transactional tag on the service layer where the repo call is being made.

> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an
>   update/delete query
>           at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:54)

I keep getting this error. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are calling `this.deleteCustomersInBatches` wich is annotated `@Transactional`. This annotation is not effective here because you are calling the native method instead of the proxied one that would be intercepted making use of the `@Transactional` annotation.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're invoking `@Transactional` method from within same bean.

`@Transactional` only works on methods invoked on proxies created by spring. It means, that when you create a `@Service` or other bean, method called from the outside will be transactional. If invoked from within bean, nothing will happen, as it doesn't pass through proxy object.

The easiest solution would be to move the method to another bean. If you really want to keep it within same component, then you need to invoke it, so that it gets wrapped in proxy by spring AOP. You can do this like that:

```
private YourClass self;

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@PostConstruct
public void postContruct(){
    self = applicationContext.getBean(YourClass.class);
}
```

Then invoking method on `self` would result in opening a transaction.