# Does Quarkus @Transactional need public methods like spring AOP

Tags: transactions, quarkus

In the context of spring we always need to make sure, that a method with `@Transactional` is public and called from the outside of the service class. The reason behind that is documented multiple times in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4396530/4585698) or in [spring guides](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.0.RC2/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html).

With Quarkus there *seems* to be the same case. Let's take the following example:

```java
@Path("/testing")
public final class TestingResource {
    @Inject
    JustATestService justATestService;

    @GET
    @Path("testa")
    public Response testA() {
        justATestService.doWithPublicTransaction();
        return Response.ok().build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("testb")
    public Response testB() {
        justATestService.doWithPrivateTransaction();
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```

And here is the service class:

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class JustATestService {
    
    @Inject
    TransactionManager tm;
    
    @Transactional
    public void doSomethingInTransaction() throws SystemException {
        System.out.println("Active transaction: " + tm.getStatus());
    }
    
    public void doWithPrivateTransaction() throws SystemException {
        System.out.println("Not in a transaction: " + tm.getStatus());
        doSomethingInAPrivateMethode();
        System.out.println("Still not in a transaction: " + tm.getStatus());
    }

    @Transactional
    private void doSomethingInAPrivateMethode() throws SystemException {
        System.out.println("Private method will not start a transaction: " + tm.getStatus());
    }

}
```

The results will be:

- `testing/testa` will show Status.STATUS_ACTIVE (=0) in the console
- `testing/testa` will always show Status.STATUS_NO_TRANSACTION (=6) in the console

Is my assumption right? Do we need to make sure a `@Transactional` annotated method needs to be called from the outside of the service to work? Quarkus will behave in this case "like" spring?

Comment: YES. In the CDI world (Quarkus' Arc is a cousin of CDI, incorporating most of its goodness, while executing much of the needed work at build time), the `@Transactional` annotation is simply an interceptor binding, specified in the JTA specification (if I am not mistaken). It even has a specific priority, meaning one can safely execute other interceptors before/after the transaction. And interceptors are implemented in a similar way to Spring without bytecode weaving, so the same restrictions apply.

Comment: They need to be `public`, `protected` or package-private (default visibility). They must not be `private`. Self-interception works, so you can call a `@Transactional` method from within the same class and the transactional interceptor _will_ be called, but again, the method must not be `private`.

Comment: Folks, maybe add those as anwers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made this an answer for clarity as suggested by geoand.
As per Ladicek comment:

They need to be public, protected or package-private (default visibility). They must not be private. Self-interception works, so you can call a @Transactional method from within the same class and the transactional interceptor will be called, but again, the method must not be private. –
Ladicek
Jun 29, 2021 at 15:53

I also have some experience myself using public, protected and package-private methods working.
'private' methods are sure not to work.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the same rule applies to Quarkus: a CDI interceptor triggered by @Transactional cannot handle self-invocation.

Read the discussion in this [issue](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/7102):

> In your test you have @transactional on a method that is called by
> other methods on the same class. CDI interceptors are not applied for
> self invocation, only for external invocation (e.g. when you inject
> the bean and invoke on it).

Comment: The same thread, a few comments later, says: "Turns out I was wrong, we do support self invocation for interceptors, so now I have no idea what is going on here, I will investigate further."; later on, a fix for the bug was issued. Self invocation works as long as the @Transactional method is public.