# quarkus persist entity received from other transaction context

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-panache

```
Car.streamAll().forEach(car->saveCar((Car) car));
```

```
    @Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    protected void saveCar(Car car) {
       car.setName("name");
       car.persist();
    }
```

The problem here of course is that im getting detached entity passed to persist, but i need to commit oftenly and not keep transaction opened, because there is lot of data and i need to commit ofttenly to not get out of space error..

Comment: You can use @ Transactional only on public methods.

Comment: @Serkan https://stackoverflow.com/a/75804884/13418836