# SpringBoot - @Transactional - not opening transaction

Tags: java, spring-boot, jooq, spring-transactions

I am trying to use transaction in SpringBoot app , for some reason it just doesn't work.
Below is the code for the sample app. I have a rest api in MyRestController.java which invokes DBService.hello() method. In hello() method I insert a row into a table using JOOQ. I see transaction is NOT being created , after further debugging I see that DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin() method is not being invoked, which explains why transaction is not created.
Can any one point what is wrong with this simple code?

```
@SpringBootApplication
    @EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true)
    public class JooqtransactionApplication {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(JooqtransactionApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
```

MyRestController.java

```
    @RestController
    public class MyRestController {
        @Autowired
        DBService DBService;
    
        @GetMapping("/callHello")
        void invokeHello()
        {
            DBService.hello();
        }
    }
```

DBService.java

```
@Service
public class DBService {
    @Autowired
    DSLContext ctx;

    @Transactional()
    void hello() {
        ctx.insertInto(Prospectiveclient.PROSPECTIVECLIENT).values("val1", "val2", "val3", "", LocalDateTime.now()).execute();
    }
}
```

Creation of Beans

```
    @Configuration
    public class GlobalConfiguration {
        @Autowired
        private Environment environment;
    
        @Bean
        DataSource dataSource() {
            HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
            HikariDataSource ds;
    
            config.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/qadb");
            config.setUsername("admin");
            config.setPassword("pass");
    
            return new HikariDataSource(config);
        }
    
        @Bean
        public TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy transactionAwareDataSource() {
            return new TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy(dataSource());
        }
    
        @Bean
        public DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager() {
            return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
        }
    
        @Bean
        public DataSourceConnectionProvider connectionProvider() {
            return new DataSourceConnectionProvider(transactionAwareDataSource());
        }
    
        @Bean
        public ExceptionTranslator exceptionTransformer() {
            return new ExceptionTranslator();
        }
    
        @Bean
        public DefaultDSLContext dsl() {
            return new DefaultDSLContext(configuration());
        }
    
        @Bean
        public DefaultConfiguration configuration() {
            DefaultConfiguration jooqConfiguration = new DefaultConfiguration();
            jooqConfiguration.set(connectionProvider());
            jooqConfiguration.set(new DefaultExecuteListenerProvider(exceptionTransformer()));
            SQLDialect dialect = SQLDialect.valueOf("MYSQL");
            jooqConfiguration.set(dialect);
            return jooqConfiguration;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Who is calling your `@Transactional` method? Because you should make it public for `@Transactional` to be taken into account, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4396530/521799

Comment: Yes, this was it !! Thanks @LukasEder for pointing this out. Perhaps some kind of warning logs would have been of great help.

Comment: Here's where to ask for "some kind of warning logs": https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/new

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Spring Manual chapter 10.5.6:](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations)

> Method visibility and @Transactional
>
> When using proxies, you should apply the @Transactional annotation
> only to methods with public visibility. If you do annotate protected,
> private or package-visible methods with the @Transactional annotation,
> no error is raised, but the annotated method does not exhibit the
> configured transactional settings. Consider the use of AspectJ (see
> below) if you need to annotate non-public methods.