# How to implement Transactional for multiple updates in single method Springboot JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, transactions

I have a method with multiple update, delete and save method calls to DB using SPringboot JPA. each of those update, delete and save methods are decorated with @Transactional.
How to implement Transactinal on my userdefined_method()? so that all in case of any failure at subsequent following method would revert back previous method changes.

```
private void userdefined_method(){
    // part1 few lines of business logic code 
    orderService.deleteById(123);  // these methods are decorated with @Transactional
    //part2 few lines of business logic code
    orderservice.save(order);   // this method is decorated with @Transactional
    //part 3 few more lines of business logic

}
```

In this example deleteById has been called and Entry get deleted from table, and assume there is an error in part2, or error in save(order) method, should roll back previous delete statement.

Comment: Maybe read https://www.baeldung.com/spring-transactional-propagation-isolation

Comment: I looked at that article before writing this question, I did not get the answer to how can i achieve the Transactional feature applied to custom method

Answer (score 1):

You can put `@Transactional` on the method and change `private` to `public`

```
@Transactional
public void userdefined_method(){
    // part1 few lines of business logic code 
    orderService.deleteById(123);  // these methods are decorated with @Transactional
    //part2 few lines of business logic code
    orderservice.save(order);   // this method is decorated with @Transactional
    //part 3 few more lines of business logic

}
```

For the explanation about `@Transactional`, you can have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396284/does-spring-transactional-attribute-work-on-a-private-method)

Comment: but this class is not extending CrudRepository, to use @Transactional. and I tried with Transactional to try out to see if that works, but failed to rollback deletedById when there was an issue in Part2 business logic