# If I have a @Transactional -annotation on a default method in a Spring bean, does the annotation have any effect? Can we use it on default methods

Tags: spring-boot, web, transactions

Does @Transactional work on default methods

This won't work on private methods but not sure about default modifiers

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

No, if you by default mean on `package-protected`. `@Transactional` will only work with `public` methods.

Comment: Whats the reason behind this ?

Comment: Because Spring proxy generator by default will simply ignore everything that is not public. Please, refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396284/does-spring-transactional-attribute-work-on-a-private-method,