OutOfMemoryError when trying to read huge number of records via JPA Repository
I'm trying to get a large number of records (more than 10 million) from the database. I get "OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space". I made the getting with Pageable. But I still get OutOfMemoryError. Reason: Hibernate caches the results of all queries, and the inflated cache fills up the memory. How to fix this?
What I found on the net suggests using EntityManager or TransactionTemplate directly. But my project has a different architecture, I use JPA Repository, transactions are managed by Spring, I can't directly call EntityManager.clear() in the method that calls the repository method.
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) in the method that requests the data does not help.
My service:
    public void exportLogs() throws IOException {
        Long countLogs = logRepository.countLogsByTimestmpRange(dateStart, dateEnd);
        int intBatchSize = 32760;
        long countPages = countLogs / intBatchSize + 1;
        for (int index = 0; index < countPages; index++) {
            log.info("exportLogs: page " + (index + 1) + " of " + countPages + ", pageSize = " + intBatchSize);
            getWorkLogs(index, intBatchSize);
        }
    }

    @Transactional(value = "workLogTransactionManager", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    private void getWorkLogs(int index, int intBatchSize) throws IOException {
        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(index, intBatchSize);
        List<WorkLog> logs = logRepository.findLogsByTimestmpRange(dateStart, dateEnd,
                pageable);
        //save logs in file
    }

Repository:
public interface WorkLogRepository extends JpaRepository<WorkLog, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT l FROM WorkLog l " +
            "WHERE (l.timestmp BETWEEN :from AND :to)"
            + " ORDER BY eventId")
    List<WorkLog> findLogsByTimestmpRange(@Param("from") Long from,
                                          @Param("to") Long to,
                                          Pageable pageable);

    @Query("SELECT count(l) FROM WorkLog l " +
            "WHERE (l.timestmp BETWEEN :from AND :to)")
    Long countLogsByTimestmpRange(@Param("from") Long from,
                                          @Param("to") Long to);
}

PlatformTransactionManager configuration:
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:application.yml"})
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Profile("!test")
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "myProject.logging.repository",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "workLogEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "workLogTransactionManager")
public class PersistenceWorkLogAutoConfiguration {

    private final Environment env;

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="dbappender")
    public DataSource workLogDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean workLogEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em
                = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(workLogDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan("myProject.domain.workLog");

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy",
                "org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy");
        properties.put("hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy",
                "org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy");
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;
    }

    @Bean(name="workLogTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager workLogTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(workLogEntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}


Hibernate caches the results of all queries, who or where is telling this ?

@Transactional annotation on a private method has no effect. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396284/does-spring-transactional-attribute-work-on-a-private-method

to PeterMmm: If I request the same page 300 times instead of 300 different pages (PageRequest.of(0, intBatchSize)), all requests, starting with the second one, are processed in milliseconds. And I don't get OutOfMemory.

Thank you, I understood my mistake about Transactional.

Are the getWorkLogs calls within the same bean? If so, I suspect they are all using the same context and transactional scope of the parent exportLogs call, so not being wrapped in their own transactions. Alternatively you can inject the EntityManager context into this bean and call clear after each getWorkLogs on it as it should be shared.

I create the new class for getWorkLogs(), and it works.
