# Pointcut confusion with inheritance

Tags: java, aspectj, spring-aop, pointcut

I am confused by writing a pointcut that matches all executions of a method. I tried the pointcut that should match all method-executions of class `Alpha`:

```
execution(* Alpha.*(..))
```

with the following class-hierachy

```
public class Alpha {
    public void alphaMethod() {...}
}
public class Beta extends Alpha {
    public void betaMethod() {
        alphaMethod();
    }
}
```

If the Main-program calls `alphaMethod` on an `Beta`-instance my advice is called like expected but the Main-program calls `betaMethod` that also calls `alphaMethod` inside my advice is not called and I don't understand why.

*Aspect-Definition*:

```
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
    @Before(value = "execution(* Alpha.*(..))", argNames="joinPoint")
    public void myAdvice(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        System.out.println("BEFORE: " + joinPoint.getSignature());
    }
}
```

*Main-method*:

```
Beta beta = ...;
beta.alphaMethod(); //advice is called
beta.betaMethod(); //advice is NOT called.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected.

Spring AOP uses proxy classes to wrap advised beans. When you call `alphaMethod()` from within a `Beta` method, the proxy isn't even aware of it.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423972/spring-transaction-method-call-by-the-method-within-the-same-class-does-not-wo) answer for more information.

Comment: I am still not expecting this behavior but using proxies lead to this problem. thx!

Comment: @darrengorman is there a way to tell Spring to include inherited methods to be advised?

Answer (score 1):

The reason, as already answered, is clear. You can fix this by employing *load-time weaving* instead of proxying (I guess it comes down to a config option somewhere and a dependency to AspectJ, if not already depending on it) or injecting the bean to itself as a dependency and then implementing

```
public void betaMethod() {
    selfBean.alphaMethod();
}
```

This will work because `selfBean` is not the same reference as `this`, the former being a reference to the proxy, the latter a reference to the original, proxied object.

Comment: yes, using a `selfBean`-reference would help but it is a workaround in which I am not interested. But I will take a closer look at weaving-settings. Thanks!