# Pointcut for all methods of a class including inherited ones

Tags: java, aspectj, spring-aop, pointcut

I am playing around with aop and aspectj and discovered an (for me) unexpected behavior.

In the [aspectj-docs](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/semantics-pointcuts.html) I found the following example-pointcut:

```
execution(public void Middle.*())
```

for the following class-definitions (I slightly changed the original example):

```
class Super {
    public void m() { ... }
}
class Middle extends Super {
}
class Sub extends Middle {
    @Override
    public void m() { ... }
}
```

The description of that exmaple states:

> [The pointcut] picks out all method executions for public methods returning void and having no arguments **that are either declared in, or inherited by, Middle**, even if those methods are overridden in a subclass of Middle.

This example is working fine for me but if class `Sub` is not overriding `m()`, the method-calls from outside to `m` on a `Sub`-instance are not intercepted. Doesn't this violates the doc?

I had [another problem with pointcuts in inhertied classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774946/pointcut-confusion-with-inheritance) which is caused by the use of proxies. But in this case the use of a proxy cannot cause this behavior because the proxy should provide methods for all of the proxied class. Or did I missed something?

my aspect-definition:

```
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
    @Before(value = "execution(* Middle.*(..))", argNames="joinPoint")
    public void myAdvice(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        System.out.println("adviced: " + joinPoint.getSignature());
    }
}
```

Comment: In the sample code in the documentation you linked to `Super`'s method was `protected` and not `public`. Is it the case that in your actual code the equivalent class to `Super` has `protected` methods and not `public` ones? That might explain the behaviour.

Comment: yes, you are right, I modified the example a bit to be able to call the method of `Super` from outside. But the description states that the pointcut will intercept all methods of `Middle` and all inherited ones to which `m()` should belong to, shouldn't it?

Comment: Are you calling the method on a variable declared as `Super`, `Middle` or `Sub`. If it is `Super` it might be that it isn't considered to be the correct type.

Comment: I call the method on an instance of 'Sub'

Comment: I stumbled on the very same problem today, read the exact same doc and got puzzled just as you are. (yes ... more than 3 years later) so my question is exactly the same as yours ! Did you come by a satisfying answer ? And if not, would you mind if I bounty your question ?

Comment: Hi @Ar3s, actually I dont remember any more. But I think this is still an interesting question (even if I dont need it right now). Feel free to bounty this question.

Comment: actually I reformulated (i wanted examples to be differently stated) and bountied mine