# Authenticate Operation Before Each Action In Spring Boot Effectively

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, annotations

I have a code block like below. For each method, I call action authentication. Is it possible to do with annotation or other thing effectively?

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity getAction(@PrincipalUser user, Long actionId)
{
   repository.checkUserForAction(user.getId(), actionId);
   implement actions...
   return service call;
}
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity addAction(@PrincipalUser user)
{
   repository.checkUserForAction(user.getId());
   implement actions...
   return service call;
}
@DeleteMapping
public ResponseEntity addAction(@PrincipalUser user, Long actionId)
{
   repository.checkUserForAction(user.getId(), actionId);
   implement actions... 
   return service call;
}
```

Actually, in here my other problem is that I call repository method each time and I know this is not an effective way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Spring Security` and `@PreAuthorize` annotation.

Example:

```
@PreAuthorize("@authorizationService.check(#actionId)")
@DeleteMapping
public ResponseEntity performAction(Long actionId) {
implement actions...
}
```

And encapsulate authorization logic inside `authorizationService`, moreover `authorizationService` must be a bean and `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)` must be set.

Comment: Thanks @Dominik, this will be helpful for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470479/call-a-private-method-in-spring-preauthorize

Comment: But I try to find a solution on class level because the line of code won't be changed with method level solution.