# How does Mockito spy mock internal method calls?

Tags: java, mockito

I always thought Mockito works some some kind of proxy and things like that. But now I found out, that Mockito allows me to do something like

```
class A {
  public String m1() {
    return m2();
  }

  public String m2() {
    return "Hello";
  }
}

class TestA {
  public testM1() {
    A a = Mockito.spy(A.class);
    when(a.m2()).thenReturn("Bye");
    Assert.assertEquals(a.m1(), "Bye");
  }
}
```

This wouldn't work with proxies. How does it do this?
Could that technique be used to allow calling internal AOP-methods? (see [Spring AOP not working for method call inside another method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564627/spring-aop-not-working-for-method-call-inside-another-method))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**On Android and Mockito <5.0,** Mockito does work with proxy-like generated subclasses, and does support spies. ([Mockito mocks and spies in 5.0+ work using instrumentation.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78048050/1426891) The rest of this answer applies to subclass-based mocks.)

The reason for the different behavior is that Mockito spies don't *delegate* to the parameter to `spy()`, but instead shallow-copies the field values to a brand new generated subclass of the class (A) with all of its methods overridden. Consequently, in Spring, references to `this` from within A refer to the original instance, where in Mockito references to `this` refer to the generated Mockito subclass—including the implicit reference to `this` in the `m2()` call within `m1`.

Though this sounds like it would allow for use of AOP, I'm not in a position to test that it works, and believe it would depend on the implementation details of Mockito and Spring AOP (and the order in which the wrapping happens). One example of Mockito behavior appearing incomplete or counterintuitive is when [the object being spied upon creates an instance of an inner class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33656445/1426891) in its constructor or field initializers, including lambdas and anonymous inner classes. These inner class instances keep a reference to their outer classes, but Mockito's shallow copying does not change all references to refer to the spy instead of the original object.

Remember that Mockito is a test framework and is not designed for use in production. Also, even if you can get the two code-generating systems to work well together, will you and your coworkers be able to read/understand/debug the test a year from now?

---

Aside re syntax: Be careful to make sure you're calling the right overload though, because A.class is also an Object instance:

```
/* DANGER */ A a = Mockito.spy(A.class);    
/* BROKEN */ A a = Mockito.spy((Object) A.class);

/*  SAFE  */ A a = Mockito.spy(new A());
```

In the broken example, even though `A.class` has is a Class at runtime, Mockito will try to subclass and spy on the `final` Class instances because overloads are chosen statically at compile time (see *Effective Java* 3rd Edition Item 52). To avoid the ambiguity, make sure you're only ever passing in a Class literal or an object statically typed as a Class. The Class syntax requires a no-arg constructor anyway, so the Class-specific overload is of limited utility. You might want to avoid it altogether and stick with passing the object instances you want to spy on.

Comment: Even `Mockito.spy(new A())` will not delegate, but create a new, independent object.

Comment: `final A a = spy(new A()); when(a.m2()).thenReturn("Bye"); Assertions.assertEquals("Bye", a.m1());` still passes

Comment: @knittl Yes, all uses of `spy` create a new independent object. In the assertion you quoted, there are likely no remaining references to the `new A()`, just the new object class Mockito creates. This differs from the way Spring AOP handles internal method calls, as in the link in the question.

Comment: This answer makes it sound like `spy(new A())` solves OP's problem. Also, it talks about "wrapped objects", but there are no "wrapped" object; there's only the spy object and nothing is wrapped

Comment: @knittl Yes, the wrapping is a part of Spring, not a part of Mockito; I was mentioning wrapping only to try to address and change the OP's mental model. You say "solves OP's problem", but the OP is not asking how to fix their code; they instead say that the code works already in a way they weren't expecting. They literally ask "How does it do this?" to which the answer is _because there's no wrapping involved in Mockito spies_.

Comment: "where in Mockito references to `this` refer to the wrapped object" – makes it sound like there is a wrapped object after all (but there isn't)

Comment: @knittl I've changed that word in particular and further expanded the text below it.

Comment: Wonderful. Much better and less confusing now. Thank you!

Comment: One more question: why is the first option "bad"? It will call the constructor anyway, so in this specific case, both options are actually identical?

Comment: @knittl I think the "bad" way adds ambiguity. `mock` takes a Class to instantiate as a parameter; `spy` _usually_ takes an instance to copy from. The `Class` overload added in 1.10 is a shortcut, but a little dangerous: Class instances are Objects too, so `spy(T.class)` and `spy((Object) T.class)` have [different behavior](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/8431ae2aff383fd4f23aec34c02d22ce1d189d2b/src/main/java/org/mockito/Mockito.java#L2186) because overrides are chosen statically. _Effective Java_ 3e item 52 talks about this. It's not wrong per se but I recommend against it.

Comment: Thanks, understood! The new way is easier to understand. It didn't occur to me that this was about overload resolution, because the original revision had a static type of `Class<A>` and consequently the more specific overload was chosen. Thanks again!