# Mockito: Spying function calls inside Functional interfaces?

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, functional-interface

Mockito doesn't seem to be able to spy on function calls inside Functional interfaces. Suppose I have a simple Spring Boot App with a service:

```
@Service
public class TestService {

    Function<Integer, Integer> mapping = this::add2;

    Integer add2(Integer integer) {
        return integer + 2;
     }

}
```

And a test:

```
@SpyBean
TestService testService;

@Test
public void mockitoTest2(){

    doReturn(6).when(testService).add2(2);

    System.out.println(testService.mapping.apply(2));

}
```

The test will return 4 instead of 6. Is this expected, or worth a bug report?

Comment: I wonder if that add2 is not inline compiled into lambda making it totally separate method.

Comment: Hmm, not sure, but I also guess the issue is related to the pure nature of the mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected. Mockito creates a spy by making a *shallow copy*, and the method reference `this::add2` gets copied over while keeping the reference to the old `this`.

```
TestService myTestService = new TestService();
TestService mySpy = Mockito.spy(myTestService);
```

In this example, `mySpy` is an instance of *a generated subclass of TestService*, which has all of its overridable methods overridden to delegate to Mockito, and all of its instance state shallow-copied from `myTestService`. This means that `myTestService.mapping == mySpy.mapping`, which also implies that the reference to `this` (meaning `myTestService`) is captured in the Function is copied over.

Method references applied to an instance capture that instance, as on [the Oracle page on Method References](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) under "Kinds of Method References". The object that receives the `add2` call is the original, not the spy, so you get the original behavior (4) and not the spy-influenced behavior (6).

This should be somewhat intuitive: You can call the `Function<Integer, Integer>` without passing around a TestService instance, so it's pretty reasonable that the Function contains an implicit reference to a TestService implementation. You're seeing this behavior because the spy instance has its state copied from a real instance *after* the Function is initialized and `this` is stored.

---

Consider this alternative, which you could define on TestService:

```
BiFunction<TestService, Integer, Integer> mapping2 = TestService::add2;
```

Here, the function `mapping2` doesn't apply to a particular object, but instead applies to any instance of TestService passed in. Consequently, your test would call this:

```
@Test
public void mockitoTest2(){
    doReturn(6).when(testService).add2(2);
    System.out.println(testService.mapping2.apply(testService, 2));
}
```

...and because you are passing in your spy `testService`, it will handle the virtual method call to `add2` and invoke the behavior set on the spy (returning 6). There is no implicitly-saved `this`, so your function works as you'd expect.

**See also:** [Mockito runnable: wanted but not invoked?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33656249/1426891)

Comment: OK, almost clear. I just wonder, what is the difference to `mapping` being a normal function, where apparently the reference to `this` doesn't get copied over. And is there another way around that, but keeping the reference to the service class in the function? In my original case, I have this function as part of an `.andThen()` chain, where both workarounds would cause the code to be way less readable.

Comment: Somehow argument saying *You can call the Function<Integer, Integer> without passing around a TestService instance, so it's pretty reasonable that the Function contains an implicit reference to a TestService implementation* does not quite gets to me as it is not in contrary of swapping `this` in lambda. If it would be swapped, function still could be called anywhere without providing invocation target. Any resources (without reading code) on how actually Mockito is creating a spy (i always thought it creates proxy). Im not arguing here - just trying to understand the deep cause of this.