# Testing lazy initialization by j.u.f.Supplier with Mockito

Tags: java, mockito, supplier

I have a class `Sut` with lazy initialization implemented using `java.util.function.Supplier`. In fact it's more complicated that the code below, but this is the simplest form that Mockito cannot test. The test below throws an error `Wanted but not invoked ... However, there were other interactions with this mock`. Why doesn't Mockito count the invocation of `create`? The code flow actually enters `create()`; I checked that with debugger.

```
import java.util.function.Supplier;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.spy;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

public class TestTimes {

    @Test
    public void testCreateOnlyOnce() {
        Sut sut = spy(new Sut());
        sut.getData();
        sut.getData();
        sut.getData();
        verify(sut, times(1)).create();
    }

    private static class Sut {
        Supplier<Object> data = this::create;

        void getData() {
            data.get();
        }

        Object create() {
            return new Object();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I'd just like to say that this is maybe one of the best examples of an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (minimal, complete and verifiable example) I've ever seen on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, thanks for the well written question.

I have tested your code myself and seen the error you mentioned. Although, I have changed your code a little bit while debugging... Take a look:

```
    @Test
    public void testCreateOnlyOnce() {
        Sut sut = spy(new Sut());
        sut.getData();
        sut.getData();
        sut.getData();
        verify(sut, times(1)).create();
    }

    private static class Sut {

        private Supplier<Object> data;

        // Added de data object initialization on the constructor to help debugging.
        public Sut() {
            this.data = this::create;
        }

        void getData() {
            data.get();
        }

        Object create() {
            return new Object();
        }
    }
```

What I found out while debugging:

1. The `Sut` class constructor is being called correctly inside the `spy(new Sut())` clause, but the `create()` method is not being called there.
2. Every time `sut.getData()` is called, the `create()` method is also called. What made me conclude, **finally** that:

> On the constructor, all that `this::create` did was telling java that, whenever it needs to retrieve the `Object` from the supplier, that `Object` will be retrieved from the `create()` method. And, the `create()` method being called by the supplier is from a class instance different from what Mockito is spying.

That explains why you cannot track it with verify.

EDIT: From my research, that is actually the desired behavior of the Supplier. It just creates an interface that has a `get()` method that calls whatever noArgs method you declared on the method reference. Take a look at [this](https://www.concretepage.com/java/java-8/java-supplier) on "Instantiate Supplier Using Method Reference".

Answer (score 3):

I want to add a little to Gabriel Pimentas excellent answer. The reason why this works as it does is that mockito creates shallow copies of the spy `new Sut()` and your `Supplier` refers to the compiled lambda method inside the original `Sut` instance and not the spy instance.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52370786/mockito-spying-function-calls-inside-functional-interfaces) and [the mockito documentation](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.28.2/org/mockito/Spy.html).

When you debug your code, you can see how this works:

`Sut sut = spy(new Sut());` is now a mocked/spied subclass of `Sut` as the instance `TestTimes$Sut$MockitoMock$1381634547@5b202a3a`. Now, all fields from the original `new Sut()` are shallow-copied, including the `Supplier<Object> data`. Looking at this field inside the spy, we can see that it is an instance of `TestTimes$Sut$$Lambda$1/510109769@1ecee32c`, i.e. pointing to a lambda inside the original `Sut`. When we set a breakpoint inside the create method, we can further observe that `this` points to `TestTimes$Sut@232a7d73`, i.e. the original `Sut` and not the spied instance.

EDIT: Even though this MCVE probably does not resemble your actual code, the following solutions come to mind:

- Inject the Supplier into your `Sut` (either during construction or as a parameter to `getData`.
- Create the supplier lazily within your `getData` method (so that it points to the mockito-instance)
- Don't use a Supplier but just call `create` directly if the Supplier is not passed from the outside