# Mockito Spy : Wanted but not invoked, but it is

Tags: java, mockito

I have a basic unit test for a Service with a mocked repository as follow :

```
@Test
    public void deleteEmployeeCallsRepositoryDeleteById() {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setName("coolName");
        employee.setId(8978L);
        EmployeeRepository repoSpy = spy(employeeRepository);
        service.deleteEmployeeById(employee.getId());
        verify(repoSpy, atLeastOnce()).deleteById(employee.getId());
    }
```

When running the test, I get the following error :

```
Wanted but not invoked:
employeeRepository.deleteById(8978L);
-> at unit.services.EmployeeServiceImplTests.deleteEmployeeCallsRepositoryDeleteById(EmployeeServiceImplTests.java:70)

However, there was exactly 1 interaction with this mock:
employeeRepository.deleteById(8978L);
-> at services.EmployeeServiceImpl.deleteEmployeeById(EmployeeServiceImpl.java:34)
```

Second sentence saying the exact opposite of the first sentence...

I tried using  `verify(repoSpy, atLeastOnce()).deleteById(anyLong());` just in case, but same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`spy` doesn't alter the argument in-place, it decorates it and returns the spying decorator. You need to pass mocks or spies to the code under test in the ordinary manner.

Comment: Well, thank you, it was as easy as that, I feel bad.

Comment: @Sorikairo You had an incorrect mental model of how the operations worked. Now you know.

Comment: `Mockito.spy` is _not_ _decorating_. It is creating an independent copy of the original thing https://stackoverflow.com/a/29616222/112968