# How can Mockito.spy() return the same type while adding spying behavior?

Tags: mockito, wrapper, spy

I suspected the `Mockito.spy()` returns a wrapper around the copy of the parameter object, and the type of this wrapper is a generated sub type of the wrapped object. Then the spying functionality could be in the outer part of the wrapper, as generally in the case of a proxy object implementing some aspect.

However, it looks like not to be correct. The type of the wrapper is exactly the same as that of the wrapped object:

```
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> spyList = spy(list);

        assertThat(spyList.getClass()).isSameAs(list.getClass());
```

But then where is the spying functionality implemented? If `spyList` is an `ArrayList` then  how will Mockito be notified about the different calls to it?

Comment: Not an exact dupe, but helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29616222/112968

Comment: Also helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14440270/112968

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mockito achieves this by using [retransformation ("HotSwap")](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#RetransformClasses), [rewriting the bytecode](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/8431ae2aff383fd4f23aec34c02d22ce1d189d2b/src/main/java/org/mockito/internal/creation/bytebuddy/InlineBytecodeGenerator.java#L376) of already-loaded classes so Mockito can intercept the behavior even of `final` and system classes. This is an artifact of the new MockitoMockMaker [introduced by default in version 5.0+](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/5.10.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#Mocking_Final). This renders obsolete some previous subclass-centric StackOverflow [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29616222/1426891) about Mockito internals, though those are still relevant on Android and anywhere else you can't count on instrumentation running.

> This alternative mock maker which uses a combination of both Java instrumentation API and sub-classing rather than creating a new class to represent a mock. This way, it becomes possible to mock final types and methods.

The best place to read about the implementation is the [org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineDelegateByteBuddyMockMaker](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/main/src/main/java/org/mockito/internal/creation/bytebuddy/InlineDelegateByteBuddyMockMaker.java), rather than the org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineByteBuddyMockMaker FQCN linked at the bottom of main Javadoc item 39. The last paragraph of that class's top-level Javadoc, emphasis mine:

> Note that inline mocks require a Java agent to be attached. Mockito will attempt an attachment of a Java agent upon
> loading the mock maker for creating inline mocks. Such runtime attachment is only possible when using a JVM that
> is part of a JDK or when using a Java 9 VM. When running on a non-JDK VM prior to Java 9, it is however possible to
> manually add the [Byte Buddy Java agent jar](https://bytebuddy.net) using the `-javaagent`
> parameter upon starting the JVM. **Furthermore, the inlining mock maker requires the VM to support class retransformation
> (also known as HotSwap).** All major VM distributions such as HotSpot (OpenJDK), J9 (IBM/Websphere) or Zing (Azul)
> support this feature.

It may also be helpful to skim ByteBuddy's [Advice javadoc](https://javadoc.io/doc/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/latest/net/bytebuddy/asm/Advice.html) for context, as well as Mockito's [MockMethodAdvice](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/main/src/main/java/org/mockito/internal/creation/bytebuddy/MockMethodAdvice.java) and [MockMethodInterceptor](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/main/src/main/java/org/mockito/internal/creation/bytebuddy/MockMethodInterceptor.java) to how Mockito achieves this magic at transformation-time and runtime respectively.

---

To reproduce this, use the following code:

```java
import static org.mockito.Mockito.spy;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> spyList = spy(list);

        System.out.println(list.getClass() + " " + list.getClass().hashCode());
        System.out.println(spyList.getClass() + " " + spyList.getClass().hashCode());
        System.out.println(list == spyList);
        System.out.println(list.getClass() == spyList.getClass());
        System.out.println(Mockito.mockingDetails(list).isMock());
        System.out.println(Mockito.mockingDetails(spyList).isMock());
    }
}
```

As on JDoodle, running in Mockito 4.11.0 (org.mockito:mockito-core:4.11.0), [this outputs](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/Xds):

```
class java.util.ArrayList 1321659788
class org.mockito.codegen.ArrayList$MockitoMock$KpRNB6cF 257459516
false
false
false
true
```

But on Mockito 5.10.0 (org.mockito:mockito-core:5.10.0), [this outputs](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/Xdq):

```
class java.util.ArrayList 1321659788
class java.util.ArrayList 1321659788
false
true
false
true
```