# Spring AOP not working, when the method is called internally within a bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-aop

I have several Aspects coded in my application. All others works except for the following.

**Service Interface**

```
package com.enbiso.proj.estudo.system.service;
...
public interface MessageService {
     ...
     Message reply(Message message);
     Message send(Message message);
     ...
}
```

**Service Implementation**

```
package com.enbiso.proj.estudo.system.service.impl;
....
@Service("messageService")
public class MessageServiceImpl implements MessageService {
   ...
   @Override
   public Message reply(Message message) {
        ...
        return this.send(message);
   }

   @Override
   public Message send(Message message) {
         ...
   }
}
```

**Aspect**

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class NewMessageAspect {
    ...
    @AfterReturning(value = "execution(* com.enbiso.proj.estudo.system.service.impl.MessageServiceImpl.send(..))", 
                    returning = "message")
    public void perform(Message message){
       ...
    }
}
```

When I try to execute the `send` method the debug point is not getting hit in the aspect `perform`.

**UPDATE**

I did some investigations and found that this doesn't work, when the `send` method is invoked from the `reply` method as below

```
@Autowire MessageService messageService;
...
messageService.reply(message);
```

But if I call the method `messageService.send(message)` it works fine. But as reply method is calling send method internally, shouldn't it also invoke the aspect?

I have no idea what i have done wrong. Please help me.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Thank you ***jst*** for clearing the things up. Just for the information purposes for the future developer in SO, I'm posting the full answer to this question

---

Lets assume that there is a bean from `SimplePojo`

```
public class SimplePojo implements Pojo {
    public void foo() {
        this.bar();
    }
    public void bar() {
        ...
    }
}
```

When we call the method `foo()`, it reinvokes the method `bar()` inside it. Even thought the method `foo()` is invoked from the AOP Proxy, the internal invocation of the `bar()` is not covered by the AOP Proxy.

[image: Proxy calls]

> So eventually this makes, if there are any advices attached to the method `bar()` to not get invoked

**Solution**

Use `AopContext.currentProxy()` to call the method. Unfortunately this couples the logic with AOP.

```
public void foo() {
   ((Pojo) AopContext.currentProxy()).bar();
}
```

Reference:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies

Comment: Another solution that I liked from [a similar SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564627/spring-aop-not-working-for-method-call-inside-another-method/13564700#13564700) was to seperate the two methods into different beans. So send would be in a SendMessageService bean and reply would be in a ReplyMessageService bean. This would avoid coupling aop with business logic.

Comment: Here is the latest link: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies

Answer (score 3):

You are running into a limitation of Spring AOP on self-invocation. You basically can get around it by using AopContext.currentProxy(), refactor code into different beans, or use full ApsectJ weaving.

See explanation here and workaround(s). 
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies

Comment: Thank you very much. this gives some light on what's happening behind. :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is the `@args` condition.

Spring documentation states the following:

```
@args - limits matching to join points (the execution of methods when using Spring AOP) where the runtime type of the actual arguments passed have annotations of the given type(s)
```

Therefore the parameter of `@args` has to be a type expression. So the correct pointcut expression is

```
@AfterReturning(value = "execution(* com.enbiso.proj.estudo.system.service.impl.MessageServiceImpl.send(..)) && args(com.enbiso.proj.estudo.system.service.impl.Message")
```

or simply

```
@AfterReturning(value = "execution(* com.enbiso.proj.estudo.system.service.impl.MessageServiceImpl.send(com.enbiso.proj.estudo.system.service.impl.Message))")
```

Please adjust the package of `Message` if it doesn't fit.

Comment: thank you for the effort and the answer. I used `args` not `@args` according to the example shown in this link http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-params-passing