# Do some action after a method call inside another method

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj

I want to do some specific actions after a non public method (bar) is called. This method is called inside another method (foo). Note that "bar" and "foo" both are defined in a third-party jar file.

I tried to do that using `@before` annotation in Aspect oriented programming using spring. [However, I could not do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30598118/spring-aop-not-working-when-the-method-is-called-internally-within-a-bean).

Could any one let me know how can I do specific thing (call a specific function) after a specific function from a jar file is called?

Comment: Simple: after the call to bar() in the foo() method, do your actions. You just need to modify the code of foo().

Comment: I edit the question. Both foo and bar are defined in a jar file, and I want when bar (private method) is called then do specific thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As *Gervasio Amy* suggested, you need to use AspectJ, not Spring AOP. If you are in a Spring environment, you can [use AspectJ within Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj) instead of Spring AOP, this is no problem. If you are not using Spring yet, AOP is not a reason to start using it, AspectJ works in simple Java SE (or EE) versions without Spring.

What you need to to is:

- Compile your Aspect code with the AspectJ compiler *ajc*. (You can also compile your whole application with it because it is also a replacement for the Java compiler *javac*.)
- Create a load-time weaving configuration *aop.xml* so as to enable your application to weave aspect code into 3rd party libraries on the fly during class-loading. I leave it up to you to figure out how to do that, just check the [LTW documentation](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/ltw.html).
- Start your JVM or application server with the AspectJ weaving agent on the command line via `-javaagent:/path/to/aspectjweaver.jar` switch.

Now what would the aspect you want look like? Let us try a few variants and refine the pointcut so as to make it match. But first let us set the stage for our experiments with a few sample 3rd party classes (`Foo` and `Bar`) and a little driver application (`Application`):

**Sample application & 3rd party code:**

```
package my.thirdparty.application;

public class Foo {
    void blah() {
        zot();
    }

    void foo() {}

    void zot() {
        foo();
    }
}
```

```java
package my.thirdparty.application;

public class Bar {
    Foo foo = new Foo();

    public void doSomething() {
        someMethod();
        bar();
        anotherMethod();
    }

    private void someMethod() {
        foo.blah();
        foo.foo();
        foo.zot();
    }

    private void bar() {
        foo.blah();
        // This is the only call we want to intercept, 'foo' called by 'bar'
        foo.foo();
        foo.zot();
        anotherMethod();
    }

    private void anotherMethod() {
        foo.blah();
        foo.foo();
        foo.zot();
    }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import my.thirdparty.application.Bar;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Bar().doSomething();
    }
}
```

As you can see, `Application.main` creates a `Bar` object and calls a public method `Bar.doSomething`. This method triggers a series of other method calls, some of which end up in `Foo.foo` being called indirectly, but only one single direct call is being made from `Bar.bar` to `Foo.foo` (which is what we are interested in according to your question).

**Aspect, part #1: intercept all calls to `Foo.foo`**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import my.thirdparty.application.Foo;
import my.thirdparty.application.Bar;

public aspect MethodInterceptor {
    pointcut allCalls() :
        call(* Foo.foo(..));

    Object around(Foo fooObject) : allCalls() && target(fooObject) {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPointStaticPart + " -> caller = " + thisEnclosingJoinPointStaticPart);
        //new Exception("printing stack trace").printStackTrace(System.out);
        //System.out.println();
        return proceed(fooObject);
    }
}
```

Console log:

```
call(void my.thirdparty.application.Foo.foo()) -> caller = execution(void my.thirdparty.application.Foo.zot())
call(void my.thirdparty.application.Foo.foo()) -> caller = execution(void my.thirdparty.application.Bar.someMethod())
call(void my.thirdparty.application.Foo.foo()) -> caller = execution(void my.thirdparty.application.Foo.zot())
call(void my.thirdparty.application.Foo.foo()) -> caller = execution(void my.thirdparty.application.Foo.zot())
call(void my.thirdparty.application.Foo.foo()) -> caller = execution(void my.thirdparty.application.Bar.bar())
call(void my.thirdparty.application.Foo.foo()) -> caller = execution(void my.thirdparty.application.Foo.zot())
call(void my.thirdparty.application.Foo.foo()) -> caller = execution(void my.thirdparty.application.Foo.zot())
call(void my.thirdparty.application.Foo.foo()) -> caller = execution(void my.thirdparty.application.Bar.anotherMethod())
call(void my.thirdparty.application.Foo.foo()) -> caller = execution(void my.thirdparty.application.Foo.zot())
call(void my.thirdparty.application.Foo.foo()) -> caller = execution(void my.thirdparty.application.Foo.zot())
call(void my.thirdparty.application.Foo.foo()) -> caller = execution(void my.thirdparty.application.Bar.anotherMethod())
call(void my.thirdparty.application.Foo.foo()) -> caller = execution(void my.thirdparty.application.Foo.zot())
```

This is a nice start, because now we can already intercept all calls to `Foo.foo`. But how about limiting the interceptions to those calls which are being made from within a control flow (`cflow`) of `Bar.bar`?

**Aspect, part #2: intercept calls to `Foo.foo` made (in-)directly by `Bar.bar`**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import my.thirdparty.application.Foo;
import my.thirdparty.application.Bar;

public aspect MethodInterceptor {
    pointcut indirectCalls() :
        call(* Foo.foo(..)) && cflow(execution(* Bar.bar(..)));

    Object around(Foo fooObject) : indirectCalls() && target(fooObject) {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPointStaticPart + " -> caller = " + thisEnclosingJoinPointStaticPart);
        //new Exception("printing stack trace").printStackTrace(System.out);
        //System.out.println();
        return proceed(fooObject);
    }
}
```

Console log:

```
call(void my.thirdparty.application.Foo.foo()) -> caller = execution(void my.thirdparty.application.Foo.zot())
call(void my.thirdparty.application.Foo.foo()) -> caller = execution(void my.thirdparty.application.Bar.bar())
call(void my.thirdparty.application.Foo.foo()) -> caller = execution(void my.thirdparty.application.Foo.zot())
call(void my.thirdparty.application.Foo.foo()) -> caller = execution(void my.thirdparty.application.Foo.zot())
call(void my.thirdparty.application.Foo.foo()) -> caller = execution(void my.thirdparty.application.Bar.anotherMethod())
call(void my.thirdparty.application.Foo.foo()) -> caller = execution(void my.thirdparty.application.Foo.zot())
```

Now this looks much better than before, we narrowed down our previous result of intercepted 12 calls down to 6. But how does it happen that we have callers like `Foo.zot` and `Bar.anotherMethod` in the result list, even though we said we wanted to limit the control flow to `Bar.bar`? The answer is simple: Those two methods were also directly or indirectly called by `Bar.bar` and are thus within the control flow. We see this more clearly if we inspect the call stacks (just uncomment the two log statements in the code):

```
call(void my.thirdparty.application.Foo.foo()) -> caller = execution(void my.thirdparty.application.Foo.zot())
java.lang.Exception: printing stack trace
    at my.thirdparty.application.Foo.foo_aroundBody1$advice(Foo.java:22)
    at my.thirdparty.application.Foo.zot(Foo.java:11)
    at my.thirdparty.application.Foo.blah(Foo.java:5)
    at my.thirdparty.application.Bar.bar(Bar.java:19)
    at my.thirdparty.application.Bar.doSomething(Bar.java:8)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(Application.java:7)

call(void my.thirdparty.application.Foo.foo()) -> caller = execution(void my.thirdparty.application.Bar.bar())
java.lang.Exception: printing stack trace
    at my.thirdparty.application.Bar.foo_aroundBody3$advice(Bar.java:22)
    at my.thirdparty.application.Bar.bar(Bar.java:21)
    at my.thirdparty.application.Bar.doSomething(Bar.java:8)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(Application.java:7)

call(void my.thirdparty.application.Foo.foo()) -> caller = execution(void my.thirdparty.application.Foo.zot())
java.lang.Exception: printing stack trace
    at my.thirdparty.application.Foo.foo_aroundBody1$advice(Foo.java:22)
    at my.thirdparty.application.Foo.zot(Foo.java:11)
    at my.thirdparty.application.Bar.bar(Bar.java:22)
    at my.thirdparty.application.Bar.doSomething(Bar.java:8)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(Application.java:7)

call(void my.thirdparty.application.Foo.foo()) -> caller = execution(void my.thirdparty.application.Foo.zot())
java.lang.Exception: printing stack trace
    at my.thirdparty.application.Foo.foo_aroundBody1$advice(Foo.java:22)
    at my.thirdparty.application.Foo.zot(Foo.java:11)
    at my.thirdparty.application.Foo.blah(Foo.java:5)
    at my.thirdparty.application.Bar.anotherMethod(Bar.java:27)
    at my.thirdparty.application.Bar.bar(Bar.java:23)
    at my.thirdparty.application.Bar.doSomething(Bar.java:8)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(Application.java:7)

call(void my.thirdparty.application.Foo.foo()) -> caller = execution(void my.thirdparty.application.Bar.anotherMethod())
java.lang.Exception: printing stack trace
    at my.thirdparty.application.Bar.foo_aroundBody5$advice(Bar.java:22)
    at my.thirdparty.application.Bar.anotherMethod(Bar.java:28)
    at my.thirdparty.application.Bar.bar(Bar.java:23)
    at my.thirdparty.application.Bar.doSomething(Bar.java:8)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(Application.java:7)

call(void my.thirdparty.application.Foo.foo()) -> caller = execution(void my.thirdparty.application.Foo.zot())
java.lang.Exception: printing stack trace
    at my.thirdparty.application.Foo.foo_aroundBody1$advice(Foo.java:22)
    at my.thirdparty.application.Foo.zot(Foo.java:11)
    at my.thirdparty.application.Bar.anotherMethod(Bar.java:29)
    at my.thirdparty.application.Bar.bar(Bar.java:23)
    at my.thirdparty.application.Bar.doSomething(Bar.java:8)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(Application.java:7)
```

If you inspect the 6 callstacks, you find `Bar.bar` in each of them. So the `cflow` pointcut has done just what we told it to.

Can we get even better? How about telling the aspect not just limit the callee (target) object to `Foo` but also the  to also the caller (this) object to `Bar`?

**Aspect, part #3: intercept calls to `Foo.foo` made (in-)directly by `Bar.bar`, but definitely from a `Bar` object**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import my.thirdparty.application.Foo;
import my.thirdparty.application.Bar;

public aspect MethodInterceptor {
    pointcut callsFromBar(Bar barObject) :
        call(* Foo.foo(..)) && cflow(execution(* Bar.bar(..))) && this(barObject);

    Object around(Foo fooObject, Bar barObject) : callsFromBar(barObject) && target(fooObject) {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPointStaticPart + " -> caller = " + thisEnclosingJoinPointStaticPart);
        new Exception("printing stack trace").printStackTrace(System.out);
        System.out.println();
        return proceed(fooObject, barObject);
    }
}
```

Console log:

```
call(void my.thirdparty.application.Foo.foo()) -> caller = execution(void my.thirdparty.application.Bar.bar())
java.lang.Exception: printing stack trace
    at my.thirdparty.application.Bar.foo_aroundBody3$advice(Bar.java:22)
    at my.thirdparty.application.Bar.bar(Bar.java:21)
    at my.thirdparty.application.Bar.doSomething(Bar.java:8)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(Application.java:7)

call(void my.thirdparty.application.Foo.foo()) -> caller = execution(void my.thirdparty.application.Bar.anotherMethod())
java.lang.Exception: printing stack trace
    at my.thirdparty.application.Bar.foo_aroundBody5$advice(Bar.java:22)
    at my.thirdparty.application.Bar.anotherMethod(Bar.java:28)
    at my.thirdparty.application.Bar.bar(Bar.java:23)
    at my.thirdparty.application.Bar.doSomething(Bar.java:8)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(Application.java:7)
```

We are getting better and better: down to 2 interceptions from 6. The one from `Bar.anotherMethod` is still unwanted because it was only indirectly triggered by `Bar.bar` and our ambition is to only intercept direct calls. Okay, then let us get even more precise:

**Aspect, part #4: intercept calls to `Foo.foo` made directly by `Bar.bar`, no indirection permitted**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import my.thirdparty.application.Foo;
import my.thirdparty.application.Bar;

public aspect MethodInterceptor {
    pointcut directCalls(Bar barObject) :
        call(* Foo.foo(..)) && cflow(execution(* Bar.bar(..))) && this(barObject) &&
        if("bar".equals(thisEnclosingJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature().getName()));

    Object around(Foo fooObject, Bar barObject) : directCalls(barObject) && target(fooObject) {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPointStaticPart + " -> caller = " + thisEnclosingJoinPointStaticPart);
        new Exception("printing stack trace").printStackTrace(System.out);
        System.out.println();
        return proceed(fooObject, barObject);
    }
}
```

Console log:

```
call(void my.thirdparty.application.Foo.foo()) -> caller = execution(void my.thirdparty.application.Bar.bar())
java.lang.Exception: printing stack trace
    at my.thirdparty.application.Bar.foo_aroundBody3$advice(Bar.java:22)
    at my.thirdparty.application.Bar.bar(Bar.java:21)
    at my.thirdparty.application.Bar.doSomething(Bar.java:8)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(Application.java:7)
```

Et voilà! This is what we wanted in the first place. Let us recapitulate what we have just done in order to narrow down the pointcut:

- `call(* Foo.foo(..))` - only calls to `Foo.foo`
- `cflow(execution(* Bar.bar(..)))` - only with the execution of `Bar.bar` in the control flow
- `this(barObject)` - the caller must be a Bar object
- `target(fooObject)` - the callee must be a Foo object
- `if("bar".equals(thisEnclosingJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature().getName()))` - a dynamic runtime condition checks if the direct caller's method name is really `bar`

I hope this solves your problem and was not too verbose. I wanted to do it tutorial-style so as to enable you to understand how to solve advanced AOP problems like this one. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using Spring AOP. It will not allow you to do that since Spring creates a proxy to aspectize a bean, thus, only calls to the "proxy" will be aspectized. It means, if you have a bean of that third party class (let call it fooBean), when you execeute `fooBean.foo()` you are actually going through the proxy which has the aspect logic, but once `foo()` method is executed, then internal calls, as for example the call to `bar()` will no longer go thought that proxy, so, there will be no aspect there.

Mybe running into a more complex solution as using pure [AspectJ](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/) might help you, since it is not based on proxys, it just enhances compiled bytecodes