# @Transactional ignored

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a Spring4 + Hibernate3 project (Web) that is including a jar (Data).
The issue is that @Transactional works well on the Web project, but on Data, it seems to ignore it.

> **Fact**: Both projects are in the same package. Let's call it
>   "`com.awsmpkg`".

Here's the exception:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:67)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:700)
at com.awsmpkg.i18n.AWSMBookResourceBundle.getDescription(AWSMBookResourceBundle.java:77)
at com.awsmpkg.i18n.AWSMBookResourceBundle.handleGetObject(AWSMBookResourceBundle.java:56)
at com.awsmpkg.i18n.AWSMBookResourceBundle$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a187c237.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:652)
at com.awsmpkg.i18n.AWSMBookResourceBundle_en$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$44ff334a.handleGetObject(<generated>)
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getObject(ResourceBundle.java:441)
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getString(ResourceBundle.java:407)
at com.awsmpkg.spring.util.CustomResourceBundleMessageSource.getStringOrNull(CustomResourceBundleMessageSource.java:29)
at org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource.resolveCodeWithoutArguments(ResourceBundleMessageSource.java:131)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractMessageSource.getMessageInternal(AbstractMessageSource.java:209)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractMessageSource.getMessage(AbstractMessageSource.java:151)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getMessage(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1259)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.MessageTag.resolveMessage(MessageTag.java:241)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.MessageTag.doEndTag(MessageTag.java:180)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.selectManual_jsp._jspx_meth_spring_005fmessage_005f0(selectManual_jsp.java:321)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.selectManual_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(selectManual_jsp.java:205)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.selectManual_jsp._jspService(selectManual_jsp.java:142)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:467)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:392)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1282)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:467)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:392)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1282)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at com.awsmpkg.spring.HibernateSessionFilter.doFilter(HibernateSessionFilter.java:137)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1441)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'm_6303' for locale 'en_US'.
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:601)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:466)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:467)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:392)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1282)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:467)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:392)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1282)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at com.awsmpkg.spring.HibernateSessionFilter.doFilter(HibernateSessionFilter.java:137)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1441)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'm_6303' for locale 'en_US'.
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:909)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:838)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.selectManual_jsp._jspService(selectManual_jsp.java:159)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
... 68 more
Caused by: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'm_6303' for locale 'en_US'.
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.MessageTag.doEndTag(MessageTag.java:200)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.selectManual_jsp._jspx_meth_spring_005fmessage_005f0(selectManual_jsp.java:321)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.selectManual_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(selectManual_jsp.java:205)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.selectManual_jsp._jspService(selectManual_jsp.java:142)
... 71 more
```

It sends me to the line where sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() happens.
Class from Data project.

```
package com.awsmpkg.i18n;

@Service("resourceBundle")
public class AwesomeClass {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Transactional("transactionManager")
    public String getDescription(String key) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(); // here
        return "Whatever";
    }
```

appContext.xml from Web project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
   https://www.springframework.org/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context https://www.springframework.org/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<tx:annotation-driven/>

<!-- Web App -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.awsmpkg"/>
<context:annotation-config/>

<!-- SessionFactory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- SessionFactoryUsers -->
<bean id="sessionFactoryUsers"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernateUsers.cfg.xml"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManagerUsers"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactoryUsers" />
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource" 
class="com.awsmpkg.spring.util.CustomResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>resourceBundle</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: How are you using `AwesomeClass` ?. Is it a bean managed by Spring?

Comment: Yes, it actually is a ResourceBundle class, and i made a bean in spring.

Comment: Could please you share the stacktrace?

Comment: Is `AWSMBookResourceBundle#handleGetObject` annotated with `Transactional` too? Have a look at this question, it seems related to your issue [Spring AOP not working, when the method is called internally within a bean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30598118/spring-aop-not-working-when-the-method-is-called-internally-within-a-bean)

Comment: Oh my god you're a genius. It worked! It wasn't annotated. I spent days.

Comment: You're welcome. Proxies are a bit unintuitive ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `AWSMBookResourceBundle#handleGetObject` annotated with `Transactional` too?

Have a look at this question, it seems related to your issue [Spring AOP not working, when the method is called internally within a bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30598118/spring-aop-not-working-when-the-method-is-called-internally-within-a-bean)