# @Post Filter is not filtering the method returned collection using acl and oauth spring security

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-acl, spring-oauth2

I m trying to integrate both Oauth security and acl spring security.

Instead of below oauth expression handler

```
<sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-    class="true">
<sec:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler" />
</sec:global-method-security>
```

I used the acl expression handler following configuration

as explained in http://krams915.blogspot.in/2011/01/spring-security-3-full-acl-tutorial_30.html.

I am able to make acl entries in table.But while using the @PostFilter the objects returned by the method are not getting filtered using acl permission.

Can some one please help

Comment: Is the `global-0method-security` tag in the same context as the class/bean that contains the `@PostFilter` annotated method(s). If not security won't work.

Comment: Thanks Denium for your help. Project contains service,dao and webapp maven modules.I used @PostFilter  in service layer.even i tried using PreAuthorize annotation in controller in web app layer itself.But it still did not work

Comment: That isn't an answer. Regardless of that even if it is in the same context and you are scanning for the same components twice (ie having the same component-scan in both the `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet` will render the configuration useless.

Comment: I declared component scan in one dispatcher servlet xml. and loaded it using context loader  as below  
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>
   /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml,
   /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
  </param-value>
 </context-param>
I used component scan only once as below in mvc-dispatcherservlet xml

<context:annotation-config />
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.project.*" />
 <mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager"/>

Comment: And that makes it useless. You are loading the mvc context twice... The first time it is loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener` and will retrieve secured stuff. The second time it is loaded by the `DispatcherServlet` not retrieving the security AOP. Your setup is simply flawed.

Comment: Thank you Denium. In webapp module my annotation is being recognised after removing the above context scan issue.But how should I make web module to scan the annotation in service layer.

and also I m using oauthentication in my application how should i make sure that acl expression handler is taking care of preand post authorisation

Comment: The configuration in the `ContextLoaderlIstener` should scan for everything BUT `@Controller`s and the `DispatcherServlet` should only contain/scan web related beans (like `@Controller`s) that prevents duplication of beans and saves memory and debugging weird AOP issues. Now in both the contexts add the `global-method-security` element with a reference to the correct expression handler (which should be in the security context which should only be loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener`).

Comment: Denim, I tried keeping global-method-security in both dispatcherservlet and contextLoader Listener where expression handler is loaded by only context loader listener .But the annotations in service layer are not being recognised.

Answer (score 1):

In my configuration I made two mistakes which made @PostFilter inactive.

1. As told by Denim in the above comments I loaded component scan twice once by dispatcher servlet and again i loaded dispatcher servlet xml using context loader listener.With this change i was able to detect the annotation in the package where i declared the context i,e webapplication module.but in my service module the annotation was not being detected.

2 the issue in my service layer is

I had my service class as below and applied annotation as below

```
@Service("a")
@Transactional    
Class A{

public List<Users> getUsers() {
getNames();
}

@PostFilter("hasPermission(filterObject,'edit')")
 public List<Users> getNames() {

}
```

The annotation will not be considered as both the methods will be in the same proxy can refer

the following url

[Spring AOP not working for method call inside another method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564627/spring-aop-not-working-for-method-call-inside-another-method)