# X-Ray trace doesn't shows inner method call

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-xray

I'm new to aws x-ray and trying to use x-ray with AOP based approach in a springboot application. I was able to get the traces in the aws console, but traces doesn't show inner method call method2() details. Am I missing anything here.

**Controller class**

```
import com.amazonaws.xray.spring.aop.XRayEnabled;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/xray")
@XRayEnabled
public class XrayController {

  @GetMapping(value = "/method1")
  public String method1() {
    return method2();
  }

  public String method2() {
    return "Hello";
  }
}
```

**Aspect Class**

```
import com.amazonaws.xray.entities.Subsegment;
import com.amazonaws.xray.spring.aop.BaseAbstractXRayInterceptor;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Map;


@Aspect
@Component
public class XRayInspector extends BaseAbstractXRayInterceptor {
  @Override
  protected Map<String, Map<String, Object>> generateMetadata(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint, Subsegment subsegment)  {
    return super.generateMetadata(proceedingJoinPoint, subsegment);
  }

  @Override
  @Pointcut("@within(com.amazonaws.xray.spring.aop.XRayEnabled) && (bean(*Controller) || bean(*Service) || bean(*Client) || bean(*Mapper))")
  public void xrayEnabledClasses() {}
}
```

**When I hit http://localhost:8080/xray/method1 endpoint,**
**AWS Xray Console doesn't show method2() details**

[image: AWS Xray Console doesn't show method2 details]

Comment: and what happens if you move method2 to a different class?

Comment: The tracing works with AOP, aop is, by default, applied with proxies. Drawback of proxy based AOP is that it doesn't work with internal method calls (from object A to Object A), only external method calls (from object A to Object b) are intercepted. the easy way to solve this is do only external calls, else you will need to use eitehr load- or compile time weaving with full blown AspectJ to make it work.

Comment: @DarrenForsythe still same, only one method shows. I cannot get second level method details. Tried putting method2() to separate Service class and invoking too.

Comment: M.Deinum I see, I didn't think of that. will try without AOP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I later understood with the use of M. Deinum's comment AOP prevents you to wrap a function if it is in the caller is in the same class of the callee.

Read more on AOP https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies

You can use a work around using below self injection

```
public class Test {


  @Autowire 
  private Test test;


  public void method1(){
     .........
     test.method2();
    ...........
  }


  public void method2(){
    ...............
    ...............  
  }
}
```

notice here we call the method 2 by test.method2(); instead of this.method2()

I referred below answer also for this solution [Spring AOP not working for method call inside another method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564627/spring-aop-not-working-for-method-call-inside-another-method)