# Spring Data JPA - How to have multiple transaction boundaries with same TransactionManager

Tags: spring, jpa

I have a service which has to perform the following steps in sequence.

```
1) insert database records
2) commit
3) call external service (This service need to see the inserts in step 1)
4) more inserts
5) commit
```

Currently the external service is not able to see the inserted rows.
Please suggest how to make the commit happen before the external call. I am using Spring JPA/Hibernate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure both operations run in their own transaction and that T1 is committed before T2 executes. You also need to be aware of this discussion:

[Spring @Transaction method call by the method within the same class, does not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423972/spring-transaction-method-call-by-the-method-within-the-same-class-does-not-wo)

Given the above something like this should work:

```
@Service
public class ClientService{

    @Autowired
    private RecordsService recordsService;

    @Autowired 
    private ExternalService externalService;

    public void insert(){
        recordsService.insertRecords();
        externalService.insertRecords();
    }
}

@Service
public class RecordsService{

    @Transactional
    public void insertRecords(){

    }
}

@Service
public class ExternalService{

    @Transactional
    public void insertRecords(){

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alan for the prompt response. Appreciate it.