# Transaction not rolling back Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-transactions

Below is my code for applicationContext.xml and my serviceImpl class.

I have  added and @ service and @Transactional added to my code.

But the transaction is not rolling back on exception. It inserts into table 1 even thought table2 insert fails.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd">

<!-- Persistence layer -->
<context:annotation-config />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.tax.data" />

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
          <property name="dataSource" ref="oracleds" /> 
   </bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />

<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="oracleds" />
<property name="configLocation" value="classpath:config/myBatis-config.xml" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
<property name="basePackage" value="com.tax.data.persistence.mapper" />
</bean>

<bean id="oracleds"
class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
<property name="url" value="${ORACLE_DB_URL}" />
<property name="username" value="${ORACLE_DB_USER}" />         
<property name="password" value="${ORACLE_DB_PWD}" />       
</bean>  

</beans>
```

Service class pseudo

```
@Service
public class EditTaxServiceImpl implements taxService{
private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(EditTaxServiceImpl.class);
@Autowired
private TaxMapper taxMapper;

//..//


@Override
   @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = DataException.class)
   public void insertUserTaxRequest(UserRequest userRequest, TaxProcess taxProcess) throws DataException{      
       UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo();
       InterfaceInfo interfaceInfo = new InterfaceInfo();
       TaxInfo taxInfo = new TaxInfo();    
    try{
       ///..///

        taxMapper.insertUserInfo(userInfo);

        taxMapper.insertTaxInfo(taxInfo);

        taxMapper.insertTaxEditInfo(taxInfo);


    } catch (Exception ex) {

        throw new DataException("EditTaxServiceImpl Service : Error in inserting EditTaxServiceImpl"+  ex.getMessage());
    }


    } 


}
```

Exception class

```
package com.tax.data.exception;

public class DataException extends Exception {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1553804688073838262L;

    public DataException( String message) {
        super(message);
    }


}
```

Comment: I think you need to add the `datasource` to the `txManager`, something like this `<property name="dataSource" ref="oracleds"/>`

Comment: Why are you using the `JtaTransactionManager`? You are using the `DriverManagerDataSource` which isn't XA capably. You also have a single resource so why use it? Use the `DataSourceTransactionManager` instead and inject the datasource into it.

Comment: @ M. Deinum I have added DataSourceTransactionManager and updated the code y injecting data source, still rollback wouldnt work.

Comment: you are catching this exception and consuming it and not propagating the exception

Comment: Can you please post code for `DataException` ?

Comment: @ user3145373 ツ added exception code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling this method from within this service, then this might be the classic issue of calling a `@Transactional` annotated method *from within the same class*. This scenario does not utilize the proxy class that is created containing the functional annotated `@Transactional` method.

See [this other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423972/spring-transaction-method-call-by-the-method-within-the-same-class-does-not-wo) for a related explanation.

The solution is to simply factor out this method into another class and inject into the bean you want to call. You should be able to call the method that way since it will be wrapped in the transactional proxy object.