# Transactional rollback for caught exception not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, transactional

@Transactional isn't rolling back the transaction when I'm throwing the exception in a catch block.

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = MyException.class)
public void testTransactional2() throws Exception {
    try {
        dao1.save(entity1);
        dao2.save(entity2);
        arrayList.get(999999); // intentionally cause an exception
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        throw new MyException(ErrorCode.UNABLE_TO_INSERT, e);
    }
}
```

`dao1.save()` and `dao2.save()` are both annotated with `@Transactional` themselves.

When I check the database, I see both the entities are persisted.

Comment: Where is the method called from? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423972/spring-transaction-method-call-by-the-method-within-the-same-class-does-not-wo

Comment: How are you calling this method and which database are you using.

Comment: This method is called from another method in the same class which is NOT annotated as Transactional. The parent method is called from a controller. The thrown exception is caught there but I have tested it without catching as well - same result.

Comment: The link I have posted above is relevant then. I think in this case you actually have 2 separate transactions executed - those defined at the DAO level - as the transaction defined at the service layer has no effect.

Comment: If you are calling it from the same class the `@Transactional` is useless. You have 2 transactions for both save methods. Calling proxied methods on the same class won't work as they don't pass though the proxy.

Comment: By default, Spring @Transactional uses Propagation.REQUIRED. So shouldn't the transactions in the two DAOs use the existing transaction?

Comment: As is clearly explained above your `@Transactional` in question has zero effect. I am not sure how his could be made any clearer.

Comment: I got that (calling a `@Transactional` method from another method within the same class renders the annotation useless). I was trying to understand why this is the case. Thanks for your explanation. :)

Answer (score -1):

Note : @Transactional is setup to rollback, by default, only when an unchecked exception is thrown.

Along with this remove your throws clause , instead throws MyException.

Comment: I am throwing `MyException` from the catch block and `@Transactional` is set to `rollbackFor=MyException.class`. So there's not problem with that.