# Spring Data @Query to Create MySQL Event

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I want to create MySQL Event programmatically with Query Method (@Query) in spring data. And my code like this:

TestService.java

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void saveAndCreateEvent(Test test) {
    save(test);

    testStartEvent(test);
    testEndEvent(test);
}

@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void save(Test test){
    testRepository.save(test);
}

@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void testStartEvent(Test test){
    byte statusId = 2;//Open
    testRepository.createEventTestOpen(test.getId(), statusId, test.getStartDate());
};
```

TestRepository.java

```
@Query(value="DELIMITER |"
        + " CREATE EVENT test_open"
        + "     ON SCHEDULE AT :date"
        + "     DO"
        + "         BEGIN"
        + "             UPDATE `test`"
        + "                 SET `test_status_id` = :statusId"
        + "                 WHERE `id` = :id ;"
        + "             UPDATE `user`"
        + "                 SET ...
        + "                 WHERE `id` = (SELECT `user_id` FROM `test_participant` WHERE `test_id` = :id);"
        + "         END |"
        + " DELIMITER ;", nativeQuery=true)
public void createEventTestOpen(
        @Param("id") Long id,
        @Param("statusId") byte statusId,
        @Param("date") Date date);
```

But i get error like this:

> o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
>   o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER |
>   CREATE EVENT test_open      ON SCHEDULE AT '2019-02-27 05:20:0' at line 1
>   The Ex: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement

I call saveAndCreateEvent() method to save test details and create start_event and end_event in MySQL.
The problem occurred in method testStartEvent() that call createEventTestOpen().

I guess that happen because `DELIMITER |`.
If I change query, without `delimiter` and only one update statement in body (first one), it work fine.

**UPDATED 27 Feb 2019** : This method is not work fine. This query also cause commit transaction immediately.

```
@Query(value="CREATE EVENT test_open"
        + "     ON SCHEDULE AT :date"
        + "     DO"
        + "         UPDATE `test`"
        + "             SET `test_status_id` = :statusId"
        + "             WHERE `id` = :id ;", nativeQuery=true)
public void createEventTestOpen(
        @Param("id") Long id,
        @Param("statusId") byte statusId,
        @Param("date") Date date);
```

If I change query, without `delimiter` and with two update statement in body it work too, but transaction committed before method testEndEvent().

```
@Query(value="CREATE EVENT test_open"
        + "     ON SCHEDULE AT :date"
        + "     DO"
        + "         BEGIN"
        + "             UPDATE `test`"
        + "                 SET `test_status_id` = :statusId"
        + "                 WHERE `id` = :id ;"
        + "             UPDATE `user`"
        + "                 SET ...
        + "                 WHERE `id` = (SELECT `user_id` FROM `test_participant` WHERE `test_id` = :id);"
        + "         END", nativeQuery=true)
public void createEventTestOpen(
        @Param("id") Long id,
        @Param("statusId") byte statusId,
        @Param("date") Date date);
```

I am using spring-boot-starter-parent version 1.5.13.RELEASE.

How can I make a MySQL event with delimiter using the query method in Spring...?

Comment: 1st.: Does the "statement" (with delimiter) run on db? (without SQL Error ... i doubt so.)

Comment: @xerx593 yes, it work on db, i run on MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 0):

The most frequently error occurred on `SQL Error: 1064` is when we use reserved words in our sql definition. Try changing the name to de `date` parameter. I hope this can be useful to you

Comment: Problem is not in date parameter name. `:date` here is named parameter binding, not reserved word (MySQL Keyword). It will not threat as variable name. As I say before, if I change query without delimiter it will work even using `:date`.

Answer (score 0):

## `delimiter`

is a

> ..command of the [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html) (CLI tool)...

(..and only a "hack" to "deactivate the normal function of `;`" in [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html) (CLI tool).)

..it is *not* an SQL command! (and of course throws SQL Error: 1064...)

In your case (**You don't need `delimiter` at all**), you can just use the semicolons and `BEGIN`, `DECLARE`, `END`, ... "as needed", and "rely" on the capabilities of the driver.

->

> If I change query, without delimiter and with two update statement in body it work too

---

## The other issue:

> but transaction committed before method testEndEvent().

...We have to few infos, but, according to your code, *could* be this:

[Spring @Transaction method call by the method within the same class, does not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3423972/592355)

Comment: Thank you for the informations xerx593. Calling method in same class with Transactional annotation that cause this.
From [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html), I found self-invocation in proxy mode transaction (which is the default) will not lead to an actual transaction at runtime even if the invoked method is marked with @Transactional.