# Spring data jpa with multiple entities not rolling back - PostgreSQL

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, transactions, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring-data-jpa in one of my projects. In service layer, I have annotated a private method with @Transactional and also enabled @EnableTransactionManagement in application. When one of the save method of entities throws an exception, the rest of the entities which were saved before are not rolling back. BTW I am using PostgreSQL.

Please let me know if I am missing anything here.

Comment: "A private method" indicates that most likely [this is your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423972/spring-transaction-method-call-by-the-method-within-the-same-class-does-not-wo). (Note the solution is a decade old and obsolete in its particulars, but the principle is the same.)

Comment: @chrylis Changing the method to the public worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring transaction will only work with **public** method. As it need to inject code using proxy classes for transactions. So making your method public will resolve your issue. Have a look on documentation of [proxy mechanism of spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxying).

Answer (score 0):

Spring by default will rollback only for Runtime Exceptions (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/transaction.html#transaction-declarative).

If you want to rollback for any exception, you could try adding:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
```