# Should @Transactional method roll back in case of calling a private method which throws RuntimeException in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, rollback, unchecked-exception

Should transaction rolled back here?

```
@Service
public class Serv {
    @Transactional
    public void method1() {
        method2();
    }
    private void method2(){
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

Or does it depend on something?

( Before today I was 100% sure in the described behavior. But an interviewer said it depends. I disagreed with him but of course it doesn't help.)

Comment: In this code it should rollback.

Comment: Did the interviewer explain what it depends on? may be how method1 called?

Comment: Did the interviewer provide the code you've posted or is it based on your interpretation of the question? While it's true that the code you posted should roll back perhaps the interviewer meant something else.

Comment: Ok, guys, thank you, I see there are no problem, just I should have to clarify from him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optimal/usual result is rollback as you answered, but interviewer said general statement as *it depends*

Maybe the interviewer meant to check if you know when it won't rollback as expected

Meaning that you shouldn't assume `@Transactional` is actually working, it should be checked first, because if `@Transactional` isn't working there'll be no rollback.

For example, in case of [calling transactional method in same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423972/spring-transaction-method-call-by-the-method-within-the-same-class-does-not-wo), if method1() is called from method3() in same class `@Transactional` won't work and won't rollback