# Hibernate: Detached Entity error on Selects after adding @Transactional

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have a big Service method in my Spring/Hibernate app which previously wasn't transactional, and was working OK. As soon as I added `@Transactional(readOnly = false, rollbackFor = {Exception.class})` to it, the **Select (Fetch) part of that method** started breaking at a Select statement *(even prior to any persistence):*

```
org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: app.domain.Activities
```

in this code:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false, rollbackFor = {Exception.class})
public String save(PlansModel plan, String id, Model model,HttpServletRequest request) throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
   //...
   //... some initial Selects - NO Persistence yet
   Project proj = planService.getProjectByID(projId); // <-- BROKE HERE "detached entity passed to persist"
   // ... NO Persistence yet
   // ...
   // At the end, some persistence starts
   planService.savePlan(plan); //etc.
}
```

We're maintaining this messy code and it's hard to analyze what may have caused it. Some objects are being modified there.

We decided to work around it by putting `@Transactional` just around the actual persistence bottom part, which is all that matters for transactionality. (Our goal is to ensure that this whole method has transactionality/rollback.)

But when we did that, we found that in this new design, transactions don't get rolled back in case of errors. We've split it up into 2 methods, and just the 2nd method is `@Transactional`, but there's no rollback from here, and the Transaction mechanism doesn't kick in. Everywhere else it works.

```
public String save(PlansModel plan, String id, Model model,HttpServletRequest request) throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
   //...
   //... some initial Selects - NO Persistence yet
   Project proj = planService.getProjectByID(projId); // <-- WORKING AGAIN without @Transactional
   // ... NO Persistence yet
   // ...
   return persistPart(..); // for persistence
}

@Transactional(readOnly = false, rollbackFor = {Exception.class})
public String persistPart(..) {

   planService.savePlan(plan); // <-- NO ROLLBACK from here
}
```

It seems like we're dealing with a method which has some issues as soon as `@Transactional` is added, but we need to ensure transactionality/rollback is enabled for it. Based on these symptoms, does anyone know what the solution might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Transactional` doesn't work when you call this method from inside the service class like you do. It's true not only for `@Transactional`. It's a limitation of Spring AOP.

Your question is almost a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423972/spring-transaction-method-call-by-the-method-within-the-same-class-does-not-wo). So you either need to inject this service into itself and call this transactional method on the injected object OR create another service which will call this transactional method