# Run code without transaction in transactional mehod spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, transactions

I have service like this:

```
class ServiceImpl implements Service {
   @Override
   @Transactional
   public int method() {
      //some logic in transaction
      method2();//I want run this without transaction
      return 2;
   }

   @Override
   @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
   public void method2() {
     //external api call
   }
}
```

How can I run method2 without transaction or in new transaction?
Can I run in my controller class this 2 method like this:

```
service.method();
service.method2();
```

Comment: what is the need to run in new transaction?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/3423972/2039546

Comment: @ShrikarKalagi in first transaction i save data to database, and i need it to be save as soon as possiible, in the second transaction i call rest api to other client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Transactional is powered by Aspect-Oriented Programming. Therefore, processing occurs when a bean is called from another bean. You can resolve this problem by

- self-inject

```
class ServiceImpl implements Service {

   @Lazy private final Service self;
   @Override
   @Transactional
   public int method() {
      //some logic in transaction
      self.method2();//I want run this without transaction
      return 2;
   }

   @Override
   @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
   public void method2() {
     //external api call
   }
}
```

- create another bean.

```
class ServiceImpl implements Service {

   private final ExternalService service;
   @Override
   @Transactional
   public int method() {
      //some logic in transaction
      method2();//I want run this without transaction
      return 2;
   }

   @Override
   public void method2() {
     service.method2();
   }
}

@Service
class ExternalService{

   @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
   public void method2() {
     //external api call
   }
}
```

Comment: What if I call in controller method my transactional methods like this: 
service.method();
service.method2();
It will be One transaction? or two ?

Comment: two different transaction

Comment: So it could be also a solution? Since I have two proxies?

Comment: Now I don't know what do you want to achieve. When you called `service.method()` invoked the method `method` will have a separate transaction. If you called `service.method2` also same situation

Comment: But if I will invoke in method(){method2()} it will be one transaction?

Comment: No, will be two, but you asked `How can I run method2 without transaction or in new transaction` so if you want disable transaction from method2 change propagation to NOT_SUPPORTED. You cannot achieve one transaction when both method are using separeted transactions by propagation REQUIRED and REQUIRES_NEW.

Comment: when I call method2() in method() I have sonar issue on method2() : "@Transactional requirement is incompatible with the one for this method." It is okey ? in method2() i set     @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)

Comment: Try to organize your code by using another bean to manage transactions