# Spring Events On Throwing Exceptions

Tags: spring-boot, events, spring-security, transactions, spring-transactions

I am implementing spring security in my application and I want to prevent brute force password attempts for a particular user account.
Whenever a user tries to login with invalid credentials, I am throwing an AuthException() with a basic Invalid Username Or Password message and in addition to I now want to increase a counter in my database for password_attempt to handle brute force attack.

I tried implementing a case where I run a separate transaction using Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW but when throwing exception from outer transaction, inner transaction is also rolled back. How to prevent this?

Also I read it somewhere when searching about it to use spring application events to handle this implementation. But will it be a bad design? Because from UserAuthenticationService I will publish an event, the event will again @Autowired UserAuthenticationService and call the function to increase the counter in the database.
Or is there a way to call the spring event automatically whenever I throw AuthException Or BadCredentialException so that I dont have to publish it explicitly?

**PS: I have added @Transactional on class level (UserAuthenticationService.class) snd both methods are in the same class**

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void updatePasswordAttempt(Long userId, Integer attemptCount){
  userRepository.updatePasswordAttempt(userId, attemptCount);
}

public void validatePassword(String password, UserEntity user){
  if(Boolean.TRUE.equals(matchPassword(password, user.getPassword()))){
    if(user.getPasswordAttempt().equals(0)) return;
  updatePasswordAttempt(user.getId(), 0);
  return;
  }

  int attemptCount = user.getPasswordAttempt() + 1;
  updatePasswordAttempt(user.getId(), attemptCount);
  throw new AuthException(INVALID_PASSWORD.getMessage(), INVALID_PASSWORD.getCode());
}
```

Comment: Assuming those two methods are in the same class, the `@Transactional` won't have an effect, because the `@Transactional` is implemented using bean wrapping. Method calls made to `this` (implicit or explicit) don't go through the bean wrapper. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423972/spring-transaction-method-call-by-the-method-within-the-same-class-does-not-wo

Comment: Ok got the point. But what is the workaround solution? Are spring events useful here and how to implement it to follow a good design principles?