# How can I pass a method into a functional interface for a retry and have it be generic?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, generics, functional-interface

I want to a create a functional interface or default method where I pass in a jpa repository method such as `findById` or `findByNumber` and have it return a generic type; this way I annotate it with `@Retryable` if the application fails to connect to db. Below are examples of methods I want passed through the functional interface:

```
Employee employee = repository.findById("2ed21");
Record record = repository.findbyNumber(311);
```

Comment: There seems to be some duplicate text in your question, but more importantly, you haven't asked one. Where are you stuck? Please read [ask].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a simple method with a `Supplier` as a parameter where you can put literally anything?

```
@Retryable(...)
public <T> T retry(Supplier<T> supplier) {
    return supplier.get();
}
```

Usage:

```java
Employee employee = retry(() -> repository.findById("2ed21"));
Record record = retry(() -> repository.findbyNumber(311));
```

Few notes:

- You need to invoke a method annotated with `@Retryable` from a different bean to overcome a limitation of Spring AOP. To be honest I have never worked with `@Retryable` but I guess it would work the same way as `@Transactional`, related: [Spring @Transaction method call by the method within the same class, does not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3423972/3764965)
- I haven't tested the solution.

Comment: Thanks for reply. That's what I end up doing.