# Will the rows added to the database in the first call to method @Transactional be visible in the second call to method @Transactional?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, transactions

I have a method `a()` annotated with `@Transactional` that calls method `b()` twice. Method `b()` is also annotated with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW). The` b()` method adds rows to the database.
These methods are in different classes.

My question is: Will the rows added to the database in the first call to method `b()` be visible in the second call to method `b()` due to the use of `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW` for the transaction propagation?

```
class A {
    private B bInst;
    @Transactional
    public void a() {
        bInst.b();
        bInst.b();
    }
}

class B {
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void b() {
        // adding rows
    }
}
```

It depends on whether the first transaction has completed as to the availability of data in the second transaction. Am I correct? Or is the first transaction always completed by the time the second one is started?

Comment: `b` method will not start a new transaction. Have a look at this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423972/spring-transaction-method-call-by-the-method-within-the-same-class-does-not-wo).

Comment: I've changed the description. Methods are in different files.