@Transactional method calling another method with @Transactional anotation?
I have two different methods in the same class. I get SonarLint error that
"Methods with Spring proxy should not be called via "this".
These two methods are marked with the @Transaction annotation. Even though I made the annotations '@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)', but it didn't solve the SonarLint error. I cannot move methods to another class. What should I do?
@Transactional
    public void processEmails(SearchFilter searchFilter, ExchangeService exchangeService) throws Exception
    {
        Folder inbox = Folder.bind(exchangeService, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
....
....
...


 @Transactional
    public void readAndProcessProposalApprovalMails() throws Exception
    {
        try (ExchangeService exchangeService = new MicrosoftExchangeDomainServiceImpl(exchangeUsername, encryptionService.decryptWithGCMAlgorithm(exchangePassword), exchangeServiceUrl, exchangeServiceTimeout, exchangeDomain))
        {
            SearchFilter searchFilter = microsoftExchangeService.getSearchFilter(false, null, approvalSubjectPrefix, null);
            processEmails(searchFilter, exchangeService);
        }
    }


Calling from same Service won't give you @Transaction behavior as this requires proxy. You can check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3429757/5332914

We ran into this yesterday. We created a separate class and method for transaction processing. The same behavior is exhibited with the Async annotation. You can't have an Async method call another Async method within the same class and expect it to be asynchronous.

To address the SonarLint error you can use one of these two solutions:

Refactor into Separate Classes: (Recommended)


Spring uses proxies to manage transactional boundaries. and when calling the method within the same class using "this' the transactional annotation is ignored because it bypasses the proxy.


Using AopContext: (Not Recommended)


AopContext.currentProxy(): this mehtod  will give you the current Spring AOP proxy for the bean, which you can use to call the methods with transactional annotations.

